# How to use a \write command inside a \newenvironment ?

Tags: environments, write

I'd like to make a new environment which would store its content in a file, so that I can read that file at another part of the document. More specifically, I want to have an environment `{proof}` such that its contents can be automatically moved to the appendix.

So far, I tried the following code:

```
\newwrite\pfs
\openout\pfs=tmp
\newenvironment{proof}{\immediate\write\pfs\bgroup}{\egroup}

\begin{proof}It's obvious.\end{proof}
```

However it doesn't seem to work: I get the error message `File ended while scanning the text of \write`. Can anybody help fix this macro?

Edit: I managed to get this macro work to work as a TeX macro:

```
\newwrite\pfs
\immediate\openout\pfs=tmp
\long\def\writetofile#1{\immediate\write\pfs{#1}}
\long\def\proof#1{\writetofile{\noexpand\par\noexpand\textbf{Proof:} #1}}

\proof{It's obvious.} Theorem: $0.999\ldots=1$

\immediate\closeout\pfs
\input tmp
```

However, I'd much prefer this macro to be converted into an environment, since most proofs will be very long...

Comment: Related: [How to place all proofs automatically in appendix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code below write the contents verbatim to a file. Nothing will be expanded and lines ar kept intact.  The `Proof` environment has an optional argument for a different file name

This is especialy usefull when you write example code (see `lshort`) with the code on oneside and the output next to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\Code@out

\newcommand\Proof{\obeylines\expandafter\ProofArg\noexpand}

\newcommand\ProofArg[1][\jobname.tmp]{%
    \gdef\FName{#1}%
    \begingroup
        \@bsphack%
        \immediate\openout\Code@out\FName%
        \let\do\@makeother\dospecials%
        \catcode`\^^M\active%
        \def\verbatim@processline{%
            \immediate\write\Code@out{\the\verbatim@line}}%
        \verbatim@start}

\def\endProof{%
        \immediate\closeout\Code@out\@esphack
    \endgroup
    \input{\FName}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Proof}
    It's obvious.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[temp]
    It's also obvious $x^2$.
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Danie -- after small modifications this code worked fine for me! I just had to move the `\openout`, `\closeout` and `\input` statements outside of macros so that all proofs get written into a single file. Although I'm still rather confused as to what the lines `\let\do\@makeother\dospecials%` and the next one do.

Answer (score 3):

There are some packages for this on CTAN. E.g. [`answers`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/answers.html) or [`exam`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/exam.html). If you want to write your own environment the easiest is probably to collect the body in a `toks` register or macro (e.g. with the [`environ`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/environ.html) package) and write it to the file at the end of the environment.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in general: You can create your own write-to-file environment e.g. using the `listings` package. I'm using this in my `ydoc` bundle to process LaTeX code examples twice, similar to `showexpl`. This writes the content verbatim, while `\write` would expand it. This is better because you don't need to `\protect` fragile macros.

You need to load the `listings` package and also require its `writefile` aspect.
Then you can use the write feature in an custom environment defined with `\lstnewenvironment` as shown below. You can also use an optional argument which is passed to a local `\lstset` to use other `listings` features, e.g. like `gobble` to remove a certain amount of trailing spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}

\lstnewenvironment{proof}{%
  % The content is stored in a temp box to avoid any spaces etc.
  % to have an impact
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox\bgroup
  % Write file to given filename
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\jobname.prf}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile% closes output file
  \egroup% End of temp box
  % You can already read the file again here
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

before
\begin{proof}
    This is to proof the proof works!
\end{proof}
after

Later:
\input{\jobname.prf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [the `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents) should handle that. It allows you to use the `filecontents` and `filecontents*` environments document-wide, and it allows for overwrites of existing files. With some thought, this should give you the functionality you need... I think.

Edit: Unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, this may not work in a new environment, and because of its overwrite function, you may need to assign separate files to each proof and wrap each proof in a `\begin{filecontents}{<filename>} ... \end{filename}` block separately. This isn't really a killer, though, since it just means you'll need to add a few more `\input`s in your appendix. The documentation is [here](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf), if you'd like to give it a look.

Second edit: something like this might work for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{filecontents}{obviousproof.tex}
    \begin{proof}It's obvious.\end{proof}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{anotherobvious.tex}
    \begin{proof}
        Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Assuming that $a|b$, we can conclude that $\exists{d \in \mathbb{N}}$ 
        such that $ad=b$. By Algebra we can deduce the following sequence of statements. If $(ad)=b$, then $(ad)c=bc$. 
        Therefore $(ac)d=bc$. Hence by the definition of divisibility we know that $ac|bc$.
    \end{proof}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \input{obviousproof}

    Given the following definition of divisibility 
    \begin{align*}
        (\forall{a,b \in \mathbb{N}})[a | b \equiv (\exists{c \in \mathbb{N}})(ac=b)]
    \end{align*}
    Statement: $(\forall{a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}})[(a|b) \rightarrow (ac|bc)]$
    \input{anotherobvious}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @pasha In essence, this allows you to define your proofs once, then use `\input{file}` every time you wish to reproduce the proof. If you ever redefine the proof, you only need do so once, and the file will be updated. The `\input`s will then produce your modified proof. Additionally, you need not define your proofs in the preamble as I have, you just need to define them before you call the `\input`.

Comment: Thank you, Jack, but your solution seems too cumbersome for my taste. I'd like to type the least, and get out of it the most. And having to keep track of potentially few dozens of files is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: A fair point, and if I could think of another solution, I'd be much happier for it. If I stumble on a better solution, I'll be sure to let you know.