# How to place all proofs automatically in appendix?

Tags: positioning, theorems, appendices

Can I place all proofs to theorems in appendix automatically? Usually proofs are written in the LaTeX codes immediately after the theorems. Without physically moving proofs to appendix, how can I place them in appendix automatically? Is there a package?

Comment: I am not a 100% sure this can do only proofs to appendix, hence a comment and not an answer, but have a look at [`thrmappendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thrmappendix).

Comment: If all your proofs should go to the appendix, why not provide them there? You can write them anywhere, and it gives you more freedom in the order you can present them.

Comment: Marc: sometime you prefer the proofs to be inline, but have to move them to the appendix for a conference submission. In this case one would look for an automatized way to do so, in good computer scientist.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This provides for at most 1000 proofs, which should be enough. After declaring a theorem, put `\fixstatement` after it. Using `\proofatend...\endproofatend` allows for setting proofs also in the document (say the main one).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etex,etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@fourthoffour}[4]{#4}
% We define an addition for the theorem-like environments; when
% \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} is declared, the macro \thm expands
% to {...}{...}{...}{Theorem} and with \@fourthoffour we access
% to it; then we make available \@currentlabel (the theorem number)
% also outside the environment.  
\def\fixstatement#1{%
  \AtEndEnvironment{#1}{%
    \xdef\pat@label{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \@fourthoffour\csname#1\endcsname\space\@currentlabel}}}

% We allocate a block of 1000 token registers; in this way \prooftoks
% is 1000 and we can access the following registers of the block by
% \prooftoks+n (0<n<1000); we'll use a dedicated counter for it
% that is stepped at every proof
\globtoksblk\prooftoks{1000}
\newcounter{proofcount}

% We gather the contents of the proof as argument to \proofatend
% and then we store
% "\begin{proof}[Proof of <theoremname> <theoremnumber>]#1\end{proof}"
% in the next token register of the allocated block
\long\def\proofatend#1\endproofatend{%
  \edef\next{\noexpand\begin{proof}[Proof of \pat@label]}%
  \toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\value{proofcount}\relax=\expandafter{\next#1\end{proof}}
  \stepcounter{proofcount}}

% \printproofs simply loops over the used token registers of the
% block, freeing their contents
\def\printproofs{%
  \count@=\z@
  \loop
    \the\toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\count@\relax
    \ifnum\count@<\value{proofcount}%
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother

% Here starts the example, with two theorem declarations    
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\fixstatement{thm}
\fixstatement{lem}


\begin{document}
\begin{lem}\label{addition}
$1+1=2$
\end{lem}
\proofatend
It's quite clear.
\endproofatend

\begin{thm}
$1+2=3$
\end{thm}
\proofatend
Obvious from lemma \ref{addition}.
\endproofatend

\section*{Proofs}

\printproofs

\end{document}
```

Each proof is stored in a token register and those registers are unloaded by `\printproofs`. Long proofs or a large number of them may cause memory problems.

---

### New version

Stimulated by Alfredo Hernández's comment requesting a fix for the case when `thmtools` is used, here's a new version that has also an addition. The command `\fixstatement` now has an optional argument to state the “prefix” for the proof. This may be important because in some languages one has to change the construction; in Italian we should say “Dimostrazione del Teorema” but “Dimostrazione della Proposizione”.

I provide an example where both `\newtheorem` and `\declaretheorem` are used; of course one should stick with one or the other. The example uses `thmtools`, but it's not required (and `\declaretheorem` can't be used, of course, if one doesn't load it).

The second change is that `environ` is used, so `proofatend` has become an environment, with a more coherent syntax.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etex,etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@fourthoffour}[4]{#4}
% We define an addition for the theorem-like environments; when
% \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} is declared, the macro \thm expands
% to {...}{...}{...}{Theorem} and with \@fourthoffour we access
% to it; then we make available \@currentlabel (the theorem number)
% also outside the environment.  
\newcommand\fixstatement[2][\proofname\space of]{%
  \ifcsname thmt@original@#2\endcsname
    % the theorem has been declared with \declaretheorem
    \AtEndEnvironment{#2}{%
      \xdef\pat@label{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \@fourthoffour\csname thmt@original@#2\endcsname\space\@currentlabel}%
      \xdef\pat@proofof{\@nameuse{pat@proofof@#2}}%
    }%
  \else
    % the theorem has been declared with \newtheorem
    \AtEndEnvironment{#2}{%
      \xdef\pat@label{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \@fourthoffour\csname #1\endcsname\space\@currentlabel}%
      \xdef\pat@proofof{\@nameuse{pat@proofof@#2}}%
    }%
  \fi
  \@namedef{pat@proofof@#2}{#1}%
}

% We allocate a block of 1000 token registers; in this way \prooftoks
% is 1000 and we can access the following registers of the block by
% \prooftoks+n (0<n<1000); we'll use a dedicated counter for it
% that is stepped at every proof
\globtoksblk\prooftoks{1000}
\newcounter{proofcount}

% We gather the contents of the proof as argument to \proofatend
% and then we store
% "\begin{proof}[Proof of <theoremname> <theoremnumber>]#1\end{proof}"
% in the next token register of the allocated block
\NewEnviron{proofatend}{%
  \edef\next{%
    \noexpand\begin{proof}[\pat@proofof\space\pat@label]%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
  \global\toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\value{proofcount}\relax=\expandafter{\next\end{proof}}
  \stepcounter{proofcount}}

% \printproofs simply loops over the used token registers of the
% block, freeing their contents
\def\printproofs{%
  \count@=\z@
  \loop
    \the\toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\count@\relax
    \ifnum\count@<\value{proofcount}%
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother

% Here starts the example, with two theorem declarations
\declaretheorem[style=plain,name=Theorem,qed=$\square$,numberwithin=section]{thm}
%\declaretheorem[style=plain,name=Lemma,qed=$\square$,numberlike=thm]{lem}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\fixstatement{thm}
\fixstatement[Demonstration of]{lem}


\begin{document}
\begin{lem}\label{addition}
$1+1=2$
\end{lem}
\begin{proofatend}
It's quite clear.
\end{proofatend}

\begin{thm}
$1+2=3$
\end{thm}
\begin{proofatend}
Obvious from lemma \ref{addition}.
\end{proofatend}

\section*{Proofs}

\printproofs

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the picture we have 0.1 and 0.2 because no `\section` command has been issued. Of course this will not happen in a normal document.

Comment: Your codes work good! One problem: If there is a paragraph break, it produces an error.

Comment: @Chang My fault, now it's fixed: a `\long` was missing.

Comment: Under pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian), your code generate on my machine the following error:

! Undefined control sequence.
\fixstatement #1->\AtEndEnvironment 
                                    {#1}{\xdef \pat@label {\expandafter \exp...
l.51 \fixstatement{thm}

Comment: @Jeremy The problem is that your distribution has an old version of etoolbox, which doesn't provide `\AtEndEnvironment`. TeX Live 2009 is really outdated.

Comment: @egreg Aouch. Thanks for the prompt answer: I will update.

Comment: @egreg Your code generate the following error on my machine. Do you have an idea what is it about? `! Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text> \inaccessible l.497 \printproofs`

Comment: @egreg I'm using the thmtools package and I set my theorem environment as `\declaretheorem[style=plain,name=Theorem,qed=$\square$,numberwithin=section]{thm}`. The code you provided doesn't recognise the label and it just says "Proof of 1.1", for instance, instead of "Proof of Theorem 1.1". Any way to fix that?

Comment: @AlfredoHernández The fix is to type `\@fourthoffour\csname thmt@original@#1\endcsname` instead of `\@fourthoffour\csname#1\endcsname`. Of course you have to declare *all* theorems with `\declaretheorem`.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I've uploaded a new version that has a few improvements and also fixes the problem with `\declaretheorem`.

Comment: It works perfectly, also using proofatend as an environment makes a lot of sense, it's easier to remember. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg How can I change the font specification of 'Proof of Theorem 1.1'? Can I make it bold-face?

Comment: @FEQ This is based on the `proof` environment of `amsthm`; load also `\usepackage{xpatch}` and add `\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}`

Comment: This looks like a good solution to the question. Is there a simple way to tweak it so that also the theorem/lemma is presented before the proof?

Comment: @AlexMonras Doable, but not straightforward

Comment: @egreg - this code breaks if you don't set the option `name=...` in `declaretheorem`. I didn't have them set because my theorem environments were automatically showing with the correct name (i.e. `theorem` environment was being captioned **Theorem**) and it took me quite a while to find this issue.

Comment: @Myridium Actually I don't really like the automatic feature of `thmtools`: playing with `\MakeUppercase` may be dangerous.

Comment: @egreg On my desktop it works fine, but on overleaf my coauthor have troubles: `l.170 \globtoksblk                  \prooftoks{1000} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.` The version of the compiler is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian).

Comment: @tobiasBora I can compile it with TL 2017 (the version used by Overleaf).

Comment: @egreg Oh sorry, I'm stupid some include was removed, now it works, thanks! Also, I'm wondering, do you have a solution to have several `\printproofs`, like `\printproofsSectionImportant`, `\printproofsSectionSimple`... In order to display proofs in different places? (of course, each `\printproof` would be associated to a different proof environment, or a different theorem environment.

Comment: @tobiasBora That's more difficult. I don't think I'd take the same approach nowadays, as there are better methods available. If you want, make a new question with some more details about how you'd choose how to distinguish the various proofs. Link to this question for reference.

Comment: @egreg sure, here is it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484183/ultimate-proof-at-the-end-different-sections-with-references-to-proof-theorem. What method are you refering to?

Answer (score 2):

I was recently made aware of the following package, written by [Pierre Senellart](https://pierre.senellart.com/), which seems to be doing exactly what you're looking for:

**apxproof**: https://ctan.org/pkg/apxproof

> The package makes it easier to write articles where proofs and other material are deferred to the appendix.
> The appendix material is written in the LaTeX code along with the main text which it naturally complements, and it is automatically deferred.
> The package can automatically send proofs to the appendix, can repeat in the appendix the theorem environments stated in the main text, can section the appendix automatically based on the sectioning of the main text, and supports a separate bibliography for the appendix material.

Answer (score 1):

`tcolorbox` offers some `recording` commands which allow to save boxes contents to be recovered later on.

`savelowerto` will save text after `tcblower` to be saved in an auxiliary file which can be read with `\tcbinputrecords`.

Command `\tcbstartrecording` and `\tcbstoprecording` define when `savelowerto` is to be applied.

More information about these commands can be found in [`recording`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=128) section from `tcolorbox` documentation.

Following code shows a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{theorem}{+O{}}{ %
enhanced,
colframe=green!20!black,
colback=yellow!10!white,
coltitle=green!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={Theorem~\thetcbcounter:},
label={theorem@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad,
after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black} %
{\itshape Proof on page~\pageref{proof@\thetcbcounter}}},
lowerbox=ignored,
savelowerto=theorems/theorem-\thetcbcounter.tex,
record={\string\proof{\thetcbcounter}{theorems/theorem-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
#1
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\proof}{mm}{ %
enhanced,
colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,
coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={Proof of Theorem~\ref{theorem@#1} on page~\pageref{theorem@#1}:},
phantomlabel={proof@#1},
attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no proof/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
\section{Some theorems}

\tcbstartrecording

\lipsum[2]
\begin{theorem}
First theorem:
1+2=3
\tcblower
Proof is obvious
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}[no proof]
This theorem has no proof to be printed
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}
Another theorem with proof
\tcblower
This is the proof of third theorem
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[1-3]
\tcbstoprecording

\section{Some theorems can be prooved}

\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

[image]

Although previous example shows decorated boxes, `blankest` style option suppresses all colors, borders and margins around text and even  tcolorbox-theorems looks like regular theorems as can be seen in [Restate theorem in separate file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333613/1952)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer here [Ultimate proof at the end/in appendix: different sections, with references to proof/theorem, restate, and synctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484183/ultimate-proof-at-the-end-different-sections-with-references-to-proof-theorem/484542#484542) where I provide a mini-library super easy to use, in order to put theorems in different places, mix them with lemmas, make reference to them, restate them, duplicate the proof in appendix and in main (nice for synctex), add comments in the appendix, link between the theorem and the proofs...

I won't write the code again here to avoid duplicata of answers, so I'll put a picture:
[image]