# Is there an "endproof" package?

Tags: packages, positioning, theorems, amsthm

You may be familiar with the [endfloat](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/endfloat.html) package, which moves all figures and tables to the end of your document.

Is there a similar package for achieving that kind of results with `proof` environments (as defined in the [amsthm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package)? For instance, the following chunk:

> Theorem 1: some wonderful statement.
>
> *Proof:* some astonishing proof.

would appear (when the package is used) in the text as:

> Theorem 1: some wonderful statement.
>
> *Proof:* see page P.

and then page P would contain something like:

> *Proof of Theorem 1 page XXX:* some astonishing proof.

Comment: Have a look at [`thrmappendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thrmappendix). I'm not sure it does *exactly* what you want, I believe it's pretty close though.

Comment: @wh1t3: indeed, thrmappendix comes quite close. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can try with the code shown [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/how-to-place-all-proofs-automatically-in-appendix/33230#33230) but changing the definition of `\proofatend` with

```
\long\def\proofatend#1\endproofatend{%
  \proof See page \pageref{pr\pat@label}.\endproof
  \edef\next{\noexpand\begin{proof}[Proof of \pat@label]\noexpand\label{pr\pat@label}}%
  \toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\value{proofcount}\relax=\expandafter{\next#1\end{proof}}
  \stepcounter{proofcount}}
```

This will put `Proof. See page nnn.` after the statement.

If you prefer to write proofs in environment form, then load also the **environ** package and write, instead of the definition of `\proofatend` before the following:

```
\NewEnviron{proofatend}
  {\proof See page \pageref{pr\pat@label}.\endproof
  \edef\next{\noexpand\begin{proof}[Proof of \pat@label]\noexpand\label{pr\pat@label}}%
  \toks@=\expandafter{\next}%
  \global\toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\value{proofcount}\relax=
    \expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\BODY\end{proof}}%
  \stepcounter{proofcount}}
```

Then you may write your proofs as

```
\begin{lem}\label{addition}
$1+1=2$
\end{lem}
\begin{proofatend}
It's quite clear.

Here's a paragraph break.
\end{proofatend}
```

Comment: Can I ask a silly question: why (in your original answer) do you use tokens, instead of writing to/reading from a file?

Comment: @SteveD Reading to a file is sometimes a pain; while it was necessary in the olden days, now we have huge memory and plenty of token registers to play with.