# Collecting contents of environment and store them for later retrieval

Tags: macros, environments, content-replication

I want to store contents of an environment and add them to a macro or command I could easily retrieve them, but I do not want to use the collect package. Are there any alternatives?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{blindtext}



\NewEnviron{env}{
\global\let\content\BODY
%i want to add content to running list and later get whole contents
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{env}
 text text text\\
 \end{env}

\blindtext


\begin{env}
  moretext moretext more text\\
\end{env}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time) answer your question?

Comment: @Ephraim Ncory: Please note: My solution works only for pure strings, not sophisticated code inside

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: just  tested it and you are right, it doesnt allow sophisticated code inside, any way you could modify it to do so? thanx in advance.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/how-to-place-all-proofs-automatically-in-appendix and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35265/is-there-an-endproof-package

Comment: @EphraimNcory: I updated my version, please have a look. The outputting `tcolorbox` is just for eye-catching, nothing more, to show the combined content more nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can print the saved environments by “name” or all of them.

This requires two runs (when the saved environments change), because of the usage of `\label`.

### Update

Since `etex` methods are now discouraged, here's a reimplementation with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcounter{savedenv}
\seq_new:N \g_ephraim_savedenv_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{savedenv}{ o +b }
 {
  \refstepcounter{savedenv}
  \IfValueT{#1}{\label{savedenv@#1}}
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ephraim_savedenv_seq { #2 }
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printsaved}{m}
 {% #1 is a list of labels
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_ephraim_savedenv_seq { \getrefnumber{savedenv@##1} }
    \par
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printallsaved}{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_ephraim_savedenv_seq { \par }
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{savedenv}[a]
Something for a
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}[b]
Something for b
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}
Something with no label
\end{savedenv}

\textbf{Let's print them}

This is a: \printsaved{a}

This is b: \printsaved{b}

\textbf{Let's print them in different order}

\printsaved{b,a}

\textbf{Print all of them}

\printallsaved

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Original code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex,environ,refcount}

\globtoksblk\savedenvtoks{1000}
\newcounter{savedenvcount}

\NewEnviron{savedenv}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{savedenvcount}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \label{#1}%
  \fi
  \global\toks\numexpr\savedenvtoks+\value{savedenvcount}\relax=\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
\toks\savedenvtoks={??}

\newcommand{\printsaved}[1]{%
  \the\toks\numexpr\savedenvtoks+\getrefnumber{#1}\relax
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printallsaved}{%
  \@tempcnta=\z@
  \loop
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<\value{savedenvcount}
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    \the\toks\numexpr\savedenvtoks+\@tempcnta\relax\par
  \repeat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{savedenv}[a]
Something for a
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}[b]
Something for b
\end{savedenv}

\begin{savedenv}
Something with no label
\end{savedenv}

\textbf{Let's print them}

This is a: \printsaved{a}

This is b: \printsaved{b}

\textbf{Print all of them}

\printallsaved

\end{document}
```

You can save up to 1000 environments, but you can change the number in the obvious way. Don't try setting the number to much more than 30000.

[image]

Comment: how about if i want to create multiple \globtoksblk eg \savedenvtoks1{10}, need help making savedenv to take a \globtoksblk parameter and also for printallsaved to take a parameter indicating which \globtoksblk...?

Comment: @EphraimNcory It's not very clear. Do you want to have different classes of "saved environments"?

Comment: yeah something like that, i want to create multiple tok blocks and be able to get their toks.

Comment: @EphraimNcory I think you should ask a new question, with more details explaining your needs.

Comment: i asked a new question with more details, hope you find time to help.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to use `newenviron` 
package instead of `environ`, because it defines a `\envnamebody` command.

**Note: Do not call your environment `env`, because it will collide with the implicit `\envbody` command always being defined for any environment by `newenviron`.**

After changing to that, one can use the `etoolbox` - list commands `\listgadd` etc. and `forlistloop` do add the current content to the list and processing later on, e.g. printing it.

You need a 'printing' command, I named it `\showlist`.

The content is glued together without any spacing between at the end of the environment code.

**Edited version -- glueing 'arbitrary(?)' texts together**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{newenviron}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\mylist{}%
\listadd{\mylist}{}% Initialize list

\newrobustcmd{\myexpandingcommand}[1]{%
\listgadd{\mylist}{#1}%
}%

\newenviron{content}{%
}{%
\noindent\textbf{\LARGE \textcolor{blue}{Environment content}}  % Remove later on!

\noindent\envbody%
\expandafter\myexpandingcommand\expandafter{\envbody}%
\endgraf\bigskip\bigskip% Can be removed
}%




% Macro showing the current list element%
\newrobustcmd{\showlist}[1]{%
#1%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{content}  % Store some content%
\blindtext%
\end{content}

\noindent\textbf{\LARGE \textcolor{green}{Text content outside of environment}}  % Can be removed, just for diagnosis/test

\noindent\blindtext
\endgraf\bigskip

\begin{content}

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Even more text and now even some math: \huge \(\displaystyle\int\limits^{b}_{a} f(x) dx\)}}%

\end{content}


\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.8\textwidth,title={Now the combined content of the list}]
\forlistloop{\showlist}{\mylist}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The last version of `environ` allows for changing the macro the body is stored in.

Comment: @egreg: I will look into it and post another solution, eventually...

Comment: i need to create more lists which could be different but \myexpandingcommand will only work for \mylist, help.

Comment: @EphraimNcory: I know, there is some problem with that, I will look after later on, but I had no idea, that you need more than one list, it was not stated in your question

Comment: Unfortunately `newenviron` appears to be incompatible with a new version. It raises an error `Extra \endgroup` only by including the package (`\usepackage`). ____________________________________________________________________________________________ To clarify: `\envnamebody` doesn't mean that literally, but `\<insert your environment name here>body` i.e. if the environment name is `test` then the macro is `\testbody`

Answer (score 5):

I leave this answer here because they were inspirational for the creation of the `scontents` package. With this package it is quite easy to do what you are looking for. Everything stored in memory including verbatim content. If you wish you can also save the content in external files using the key `write-env=file.tex`. I am always inclined to store the content in memory:)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{scontents}[store-env=main]
Something for main A.
\end{scontents}

\begin{scontents}[store-env=main]
Something for \verb|main B|.
\end{scontents}

\begin{scontents}[store-env=other]
Something for \verb|other|.
\end{scontents}

\textbf{Let's print them}

This is first stored in main: \getstored[1]{main}\par
This is second stored in main: \getstored[2]{main}\par
This is stored in other: \getstored[1]{other}

\textbf{Print all of stored in main}\par
\foreachsc[sep={\\[10pt]}]{main}
\end{document}
```

Saludos

Comment: For other uses, I think `getfrom_seq` internal (warning: internal, API may change any time!) function can be used to get the value of the variable. Otherwise there's still an option of extending `VerbatimOut`

Comment: Remark: internally it's possible to use `\tl_set:Nx \l__tmpa_tl { \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {1} {main} }          
 \tl_remove_once:NV \l__tmpa_tl \c__scontents_hidden_space_str`
to store the raw content of `scontents` into some token list.

Comment: @user202729 Do you have a specific application in mind for that?

Comment: I was looking for some environment that stores the inside text verbatim and accessible from other programming code (expl3) to pass it to Python/shell/write to file or something -- although for LuaTeX there's also the option of using `record_env` or something https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/in-lualatex-how-do-i-pass-the-content-of-an-environment-to-lua-verbatim , something similar is not possible for XeLaTeX/PDFLaTeX

Comment: @user202729 When I developed the idea for the package, I didn't think of something like that...mmm

Comment: @user202729 I think you could take a look at `filecontentsdef` and create something from there, that package was the base to create `scontents`, of course (at first sight) Lua is the best option.

Comment: (Remark: despite the package name, it provides an environment that does *not* use any temporary file.)

Answer (score 3):

This answer concerns collecting and storing the content of the environment *verbatim*. (some advantages includes executing the content with catcode equal to catcode at retrieval time, which can be done with e.g. `\scantokens`), or otherwise you may want to pass the selected content to Python or something similar)

Other options:

- Using `\VerbatimOut` from `fancyvrb` for storing the content verbatim (requires external file).
- LuaTeX-specific solution [In LuaLaTeX, how do I pass the content of an environment to Lua verbatim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/in-lualatex-how-do-i-pass-the-content-of-an-environment-to-lua-verbatim)
- [A macro written by another user on the site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373647/250119)
- Defining your own environment/command that manipulates the catcodes and `\endlinechar` manually.

---

| Method | Tab | Space | Newline | Final newline | Letters | Others |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `+v` argument type in xparse (*) | [**Does not work**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508001/keyboard-tab-character-in-argument-v-xparse) (link contains patch to workaround) | space catcode | `\ExplSyntax`-`Off`: char 13 cat other, `\ExplSyntax`-`On`: **first character is same character as `\endlinechar` (inherent TeX limitation, cannot fix)**, remaining are same as above | user specified | other cat | other cat |
| `\collectverb` and `\Collectverb` (*) | `\ExplSyntax`-`On`: ignored; `\ExplSyntax`-`Off`: Start of line: stripped, otherwise: space with space catcode | active space | `\ExplSyntax`-`On`: active space, `\ExplSyntax`-`Off`: active char 13 | user specified | letter cat | other cat |
| `\collectverb*` and `\Collectverb*` (*) | `\ExplSyntax`-`On`: ignored; `\ExplSyntax`-`Off`: Start of line: stripped, otherwise: same as space → | space with other cat | `\ExplSyntax`-`On`: space, `\ExplSyntax`-`Off`: active char 13 | user specified | letter cat | other cat |
| `\collect`-`verbenv` and `\Collect`-`verbenv` (**strips first line in `\ExplSyntaxOn` environment**) | active tab (char 9) | active space | active newline (char 13) | user specified | letter cat | other cat |
| `file`-`contents`-`defmacro` environment | Controlled by `\FCDtab`-`tomacro`, default: same as space | Active, default expand to space (space cat) | Active, char 13, default expand to `\par` | Always present | letter cat | other cat |
| `scontents` internal macro | other cat | other cat | char **10** cat other | Stripped | letter cat | other cat |

(*): not really an environment

Remark:

1. For the ones delimited with `{}`: `{}` can be used as delimiter, as long as inner `{}` is balanced.
2. The line `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` usually have to be on separate line.
3. Most of the time, the behavior with tab/newline is "the default one defined by the implementation" if the author does not do anything special with it.
   (can be changed by redefining `\endlinechar` or setting their catcode manually etc.)
4. What the active characters expanded to can be changed by redefining their meaning.
5. `scontents` macro is an *internal method*, might break at any time.
6. As mentioned in the documentation, it can be nested in most cases.
7. `\getstored` is not expandable.
8. However there's an internal method (see example code below)

```latex
\begin{scontents}[store-env=test]
\a test & test %comment

second line
third line
\end{scontents}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \my__a
are stored as characters. 
\tl_set:Nx \my__a { \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {1} {test} }

\tl_remove_once:NV \my__a \c__scontents_hidden_space_str
\tl_analysis_show:N \my__a

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

9. The environments defined by the `environ` package does not store the content verbatim.
10. The environments defined by the `newenviron` package does not store the content verbatim. (plus another
    issue I mentioned in a comment [Collecting contents of environment and store them for later retrieval](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184503/collecting-contents-of-environment-and-store-them-for-later-retrieval/513810#comment1553844_184504) )

Comment: Fancyvrb also support implementing environment that grabs content verbatim, I think. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647563/i-want-to-implement-a-code-highlighting-environment-using-l3regex/647565#647565 for example.

Comment: + I also made my own package for this  → https://ctan.org/pkg/saveenv which supports tab character & less "surprising" catcode & use in \ExplSyntaxOn environment .