# Collecting contents of LaTeX environment

Tags: environments, content-replication

I have the following for collecting contents of an environment and printing them later, it works but for my real task i want to use the **environ** package because i need to be able to have access to `\BODY`. How can i produce the same output with `\NewEnviron` instead of `\newenvironment` used?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{environ}

\definecollection{notes}


%works but not what i realy want i need access to \BODY and for that i cant  use \newenvironment command
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
   {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

%what i realy want
%\NewEnviron{note}{
%\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}
  %\BODY
%\@nameuse{endcollect}
%}


\begin{document}

\begin{note}
 First note
 \end{note}

\begin{note}
 Second note
 \end{note}

 \begin{note}
Third note
\end{note}

\section{collected}
\includecollection{notes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One of the many answers to questions tagged content-replication may help solve your problem.

Comment: See also [macros - Collecting contents of environment and store them for later retrieval - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184503/collecting-contents-of-environment-and-store-them-for-later-retrieval/)

Answer (score 6):

If your collected notes are only needed at the end of the document, you can avoid writing out files: just use token registers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newtoks\mainnotetoks
\newtoks\tempnotetoks
\newtoks\prenotetoks
\newtoks\postnotetoks

\NewEnviron{note}{%
  \tempnotetoks=\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \edef\notetemp{%
    \the\mainnotetoks % what was already stored
    \the\prenotetoks % text before the new note
    \the\tempnotetoks % the current note
    \the\postnotetoks % text after the new note
  }%
  % update \mainnotetoks
  \global\mainnotetoks=\expandafter{\notetemp}%
}
\newcommand\includenotes{\the\mainnotetoks}

% set the pre and post note
\prenotetoks={\par\noindent}
\postnotetoks={\par}

\begin{document}

Here we have a first note.
\begin{note}
First note
\end{note}

Here we have a second note.
\begin{note}
Second note
\end{note}

Here we have a third note.
\begin{note}
Third note
\end{note}

\section{collected}
\includenotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't stick to the `collect` package, there is just the way to directly write the `\BODY` command to a file and expand it there, afterwards reread that file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\definecollection{notes}

\newwrite\collecthandle%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\immediate\openout\collecthandle=\jobname.mynotes%
}

\newcommand{\CollectNotes}[1]{%
\immediate\closeout\collecthandle%
\IfFileExists{#1}{\input{#1}}{Nope}%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\closeout\collecthandle% Close it anyway
}%

%works but not what i realy want i need access to \BODY and for that i cant  use \newenvironment command
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
   {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

%what i realy want
\NewEnviron{Note}{%
\immediate\write\collecthandle{%
\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter{\BODY}}%
}%
\immediate\write\collecthandle{%
\string\newline
}%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{Note}
 First Note
 \end{Note}

\begin{Note}
 Second Note
\end{Note}

\begin{Note}
Third Note
\end{Note}

\begin{Note}
fourth Note with coloured mathematical markup \textcolor{red}{\[\int\limits \left({x^2}\right)dx = \dfrac{1}{3}x^3 +C \]}
and even with \textbf{bold font}
\end{Note}


\section{collected}
\CollectNotes{\jobname.mynotes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I leave this answer here because they were inspirational for the creation of the `scontents` package. Everything stored in memory including verbatim content. If you wish you can also save the content in external files using the key `write-env=file.tex`. Thanks @egreg for the MWE and the great answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[store-env=notes]{scontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Here we have a first note.
\begin{scontents}
First note
\end{scontents}

Here we have a second note.
\begin{scontents}
Second note
\end{scontents}

Here we have a third note.
\begin{scontents}
Third note
\end{scontents}

\section{collected}
\foreachsc[sep={\\[10pt]}]{notes}
\end{document}
```