# How to accumulate quotes and post them all at the end of the book?

Tags: quoting

I want to say something like this in my book:

```
Text... \quote{Life is great}

Other text \quote{Sky is blue}
```

I need all that quotes to show up *only* at the end of the book, in an Appendix. How can I do that? Maybe there is some package for that?

Comment: Do you also need a reference to the page? Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187478/write-latex-code-for-appendix-within-chapter-but-typeset-at-end-of-book help?

Comment: @egreg no, I don't need a reference to that page. The link you gave looks very close, but the solution it suggests looks over complicated. Maybe you can explain how I can do it using just `\def` and `\expandafter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saving text for later usage can be done with a token register:

```
\documentclass{article} % for simplicity

\makeatletter
\newtoks\save@quotes
\newcommand{\quoteatend}[1]{%
  \@bsphack % this should be transparent with respect to spaces
  \global\save@quotes=\expandafter{\the\save@quotes#1\par}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand{\printquotes}{\par\the\save@quotes}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Main}

Text here \quoteatend{Life is great}

Other text \quoteatend{Sky is blue}

\appendix

\section{Quotes}

The quotes follow

\medskip

\printquotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to add “(p. X)” at the end of the quote, you can do like as follows; the `\save@this@quote` macro can be used for further formatting the quote.

```
\documentclass{article} % for simplicity

\makeatletter
\newtoks\save@quotes
\newcounter{save@quote}
\newcommand{\quoteatend}[1]{%
  \@bsphack % this should be transparent with respect to spaces
  \refstepcounter{save@quote}%
  \label{quote@\romannumeral\value{save@quote}}%
  \protected@edef\save@temp{%
    \the\save@quotes
    \noexpand\save@this@quote{#1}{quote@\romannumeral\value{save@quote}}%
  }
  \global\save@quotes=\expandafter{\save@temp\par}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand{\save@this@quote}[2]{#1~(p.~\pageref{#2})}
\newcommand{\printquotes}{\par\the\save@quotes}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Main}

Text here \quoteatend{Life is great}

Other text \quoteatend{Sky is blue}

\appendix

\section{Quotes}

The quotes follow

\medskip

\printquotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: works perfectly! What if I need to say what pages that quotes were seen? Is it possible to adjust your code a bit, or it's a completely different story?

Comment: @yegor256 Some more work; that's why I asked if you need references. Stay tuned.

Comment: many thanks, works perfectly! Will be used in this book: http://www.yegor256.com/256-bloghacks.html