# Copy the content of an environment

Tags: environments

I would like to copy the content of an environment so that I can use it somewhere else. My main purpose is to print it inside a tooltip note.

My idea was to use the `environ` package:

```latex
\NewEnviron{foo}
{
  \xdef\bidule{\BODY}
  %more stuff
}
```

But when I use `\bidule` I get an error:

```
 Undefined control sequence ....
 leading text: \end{foo}
 Undefined control sequence \endgroup.
 leading text: \end{foo}
 Missing { inserted.
 leading text:   \bidule
main.tex:19: File ended while scanning text of \errhelp.
```

If my understanding is correct, I cannot use `\def` because `\BODY` won't be defined when I will use `\foo`. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You could also use an lrbox, assuming all you want to do is print it.

Comment: See also: [macros - Collecting contents of environment and store them for later retrieval - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184503/collecting-contents-of-environment-and-store-them-for-later-retrieval?noredirect=1&lq=1) (there's `scontents` package, for one)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't want to do a full expansion of `\BODY`, but just one level:

```
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\bidule\expandafter{\BODY}
```

or

```
\xdef\bidule{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}
```

Comment: No, I made a mistake. However, I don't really understand why I want only one level of expansion. Thanks for you answer ;) .

Comment: @Saroupille Suppose the environment contains `\textbf`: then `\xdef` will die horribly. If it contains `\mbox{a}` you want `\bidule` to contain `\mbox{a}`, not `\unhbox \voidb@x\hbox{a}`

Comment: @saroupille Do you want to grab the contents of environment `foo` in `\bidule` or is `\BODY` defined somewhere else?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I just want to have a command (variable) `\bidule` that contains the content of the environment `\foo`. The `environ` package stores this content in the command `\BODY`. But I think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Saroupille My bad. I didn't read carefully your question and did not notice that you already use the `environ` package. The answer of egreg is all you need.