# Save the body of an environment to a macro, without typesetting

Tags: macros, environments

I am trying to save the contents (i.e., the body) of an environment into a macro for later use (in order to typeset it later in the document). I thought of using the `environ` package (see the minimal example below), but I get an error if there are other macros inside the body of the environment (like a `\textbf{bold text}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{problemnumber}\setcounter{problemnumber}{0}
\NewEnviron{problem}{%
    \stepcounter{problemnumber}
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname myproblem-\theproblemnumber\endcsname{\BODY}
    }
           
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Some equation: $E=mc^2$
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Some text.

A second paragraph with a \textbf{bold text}. And an inline equation: $E=mc^2$.
\end{problem}

...
Typsetting the problems in a different order, later in the document.

\textbf{Problem 2:}\quad\csname myproblem-2\endcsname\par\hrulefill

\textbf{Problem 1:}\quad\csname myproblem-1\endcsname\par\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have what you want in `\BODY`  the error is unrelated, you can not have `\textbf` (or most latex) in `\xdef`.

Comment: Apart from this approach (`environ` package) there's also `VerbatimOut` from `fancyvrb`, or `scontents` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513810/250119 )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is never safe to place arbitrary LaTeX content in edef or xdef.

The macro you want is already defined as `\BODY` so you need `\let` not `\xdef` to give it a global name,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{problemnumber}\setcounter{problemnumber}{0}
\NewEnviron{problem}{%
    \stepcounter{problemnumber}%%%%%%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname myproblem-\theproblemnumber\endcsname\BODY
    }
           
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Some equation: $E=mc^2$
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Some text.

A second paragraph with a \textbf{bold text}. And an inline equation: $E=mc^2$.
\end{problem}

...
Typsetting the problems in a different order, later in the document.

\textbf{Problem 2:}\quad\csname myproblem-2\endcsname\par\hrulefill

\textbf{Problem 1:}\quad\csname myproblem-1\endcsname\par\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `\global\let` as pointed out by David.

Here's a shorter implementation with also an interface to print the problems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_digitalink_problem_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problem}{+b}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_digitalink_problem_seq { #1 }
 }
 {}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getproblem}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_digitalink_problem_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
           
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Some equation: $E=mc^2$
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Some text.

A second paragraph with a \textbf{bold text}. And an inline equation: $E=mc^2$.
\end{problem}

Typesetting the problems in a different order, later in the document.

\bigskip

\textbf{Problem 2:}\quad\getproblem{2}\par\hrulefill

\textbf{Problem 1:}\quad\getproblem{1}\par\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]