# How to add \cytoks to \tokencyclexpress?

Tags: tokcycle

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
Hello1
\endtokencyclexpress % Hello1 is in \cytoks
\tokencyclexpress % We start a new buffer
\the\cytoks % Print the old buffer into it (Hello1)
Hello2
\endtokencyclexpress % Close the new buffer
\the\cytoks % Print "Hello1Hello2"
\end{document}
```

The code above doesn't work. How should I fix it?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer showing how to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\tokencyclexpress` reinitializes `\cytoks`, you have to save the contents of `\cytoks` somewhere, and input that saved copy into the token cycle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newtoks\cumtoks
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
Hello1
\endtokencyclexpress % Hello1 is in \cytoks
\cumtoks\expandafter{\the\cytoks}

\tokencyclexpress % We start a new buffer
\the\cumtoks % Print the old buffer into it (Hello1)
Hello2
\endtokencyclexpress % Close the new buffer

\the\cytoks % Print "Hello1Hello2"
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the fashion of the prior question, here is how to automate it.  As before `\cytoks` holds the tokens from the current environment, but `\cumtoks` hold the accumulation of tokens from all environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newtoks\cumtoks
\xtokcycleenvironment\accumstart
  {\whennotprocessingparameter##1{\addcytoks{##1}}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\let\stop\endaccumstart}
  {\tcafterenv{\cumtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\the\expandafter\cumtoks\the\cytoks}\def\print{\the\cumtoks}}}
\begin{document}
\accumstart
Hello1
\stop % Hello1 is in \cytoks

\print

\accumstart % We start a new buffer
Hello2
\stop % Close the new buffer

\print % Print "Hello1Hello2"

\accumstart % We start a new buffer
Hello3
\stop % Close the new buffer

\print % Print "Hello1Hello2"
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can also help here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614214/how-to-use-tokencyclexpress-in-a-command