# How to use \tokencyclexpress in a command?

Tags: tokcycle

What's wrong with this code (it doesn't compile):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\flush{\endtokencyclexpress\par\tokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
First
\flush
Second
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

If I put the body of `\flush` into the document, everything works.

Comment: What is wrong is that the actual `\endtokencyclexpress` (or a suitable alternative) has to be found in the input stream to terminate it. A def'ed version of it is not sufficient.  Let me give some thought to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to consume the stream into a variable, print it, and clean the variable. And I need to be able to do this multiple times.

Comment: what is your actual use case here, why not the standard syntax `\newtoks\zz` ... `\zz{first}` to store `first` in the token register ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, what is wrong is that the actual `\endtokencyclexpress` (or a suitable equivalent to `\endtokcycraw`) has to be found in the input stream to terminate it. A `\def`'ed version of it is not sufficient.

Maybe this is what you are looking for.  While the token cycle in general is accumulating tokens, the macro `\flush` is the only one actually executed when it is encountered in the input stream.

Every time `\flush` is encountered, it outputs `\the\cytoks` and `\par`, it globally accumulates `\cytoks` into `\cumtoks`, and it resets `\cytoks`.  This is sort of like, but not the same as, ending the cycle and beginning a new one.

I haven't investigated what will happen if you invoke `\flush` from within a group, but needless to say, you shouldn't be doing that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newtoks\cumtoks

\xtokcycleenvironment\accumstart
  {\whennotprocessingparameter##1{\addcytoks{##1}}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\tctestifx{\flush##1}{\flush}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\let\stop\endaccumstart}
  {\tcafterenv{\cumtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\the\expandafter\cumtoks\the\cytoks}%
   \def\print{\the\cumtoks}}}

\newcommand\flush{\the\cytoks\par
  \global\cumtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\the\expandafter\cumtoks\the\cytoks}%
  \cytoks{}%
}
%\newcommand\flush{\endtokencyclexpress\par\tokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
\accumstart 
First
\flush
Second
\flush
Third
\stop

\print
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great! Maybe you know how to add another command, let's call it `\click`. It should print what's in the buffer without cleaning it and stopping the cycle.

Comment: @yegor256 Do you mean without stopping the cycle, or stopping the cycle?

Comment: Without stopping the cycle. I want the content to be duplicated.

Comment: @yegor256 In a sense, that is what it does now.  The only difference I can tell from what you are asking and what I have provided is that you want the accumulation to end up in `\cytoks` whereas my accumulation ends up in `\cumtoks`.  Also, the only difference between the cycle itself and the accumulated cycle is the presence of paragraph breaks, which you asked to be inserted at each `\flush`...those are not added to the accumulation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in LaTeX... would be great if you can just add another command `\click` to your example, please!

Comment: Let's continue here, if you don't mind: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614435/how-to-deal-with-the-buffer-of-tokcycle