# How to deal with the buffer of tokcycle?

Tags: tokcycle

This is what I'm trying to achieve using `tokcycle` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\flush{..} % close the buffer, print it, and open a new one
\newcommand\click{..} % print the buffer and don't close it
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
First
\click
Second
\flush
Third
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

I expect to see:

```
First
First Second
Third
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to add (if it is important) what you expect the `\cytoks` (or alternate) token list to contain along the way and at the conclusion?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. What matters is what happens at `\flush` and `\click`. How it works internally is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the tokencycle accumulates its input stream in the token list `\cytoks`.  However, here, the macros `\click` and `\flush` are intercepted and, when found, executed in the midst of digesting the input stream.  The macro `\click` outputs the currently digested input stream (followed by `\par`) and continues digesting, whereas `\flush` executes a `\click` but then clears what had been already digested in the input stream.

At the close of the token cycle, what is left in the digested input buffer is output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Macrodirective{\ifx\click#1\click\else\ifx\flush#1\flush\else
  \addcytoks{#1}\fi\fi}
\newcommand\flush{\click\cytoks{}} % print the buffer and reset it
\newcommand\click{\the\cytoks\par} % print the buffer and don't close it
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
First
\click
Second
\flush
Third
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]