# How to use \tokencyclexpress inside \AtBeginDocument?

Tags: tokcycle

Here is what I'm doing (I need this for my package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\AtBeginDocument{\tokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Doesn't compile.

Comment: tokencycleexpress isn't mentioned much in the manual but appears to require an explicit `\end..`  token to stop. Currently it reads past the end of the file so you go to TeX's `*` prompt waiting for more input

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is correct.  The token cycle requires an explicit `\end...` in the input stream (whether the input file contains it or even if the cycle implants it on the fly).  This MWE would thus fail for the same reason as the question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614214/how-to-use-tokencyclexpress-in-a-command

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes shocking first sentence.

Comment: Oh, @DavidCarlisle, nothing to worry about. You still have quite a ways to fall before you reach the "broken clock" stage.