# Wrapping a for loop inside an environment

Tags: environments, foreach

I'm trying to make an environment that wraps a for loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Testing}
\author{This is a Name}
\date{June 2022}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newenvironment{fora}{
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {0,1,...,5}  {
} {
  }
}
\begin{fora}
\textit{meow}
\end{fora}

\end{document}
```

I get this error on overleaf at \end{fora}:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

My intended goal was for "meow" to be printed 5 times. Any ideas on what is wrong? I'm guessing it's an issue related to the nested curly brackets.

Comment: Use `environ` package to grab the body.

Comment: Or one of the alternatives in [macros - Collecting contents of environment and store them for later retrieval - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184503/collecting-contents-of-environment-and-store-them-for-later-retrieval/)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying something like

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{something with #1}

\newenvironment{fora}
  {\mycommand{}% begin part
  {}}% end part
```

where the `{` in the begin part should be matched by the `}` in the end part.

Sorry, no, it cannot work: a “begin part” like that would have unmatched braces and, actually, TeX matches them in a way that you might find surprising, but it isn't.

What you maybe want is to grab the environments content and to pass it to the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fora}{+b}
  {\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {0,1,...,5}  {#1}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{fora}
\textit{meow}
\end{fora}

\end{document}
```

The argument type `b` roughly means “make `#1` to be the whole content of the environment, after stripping off leading and trailing spaces”; the `+` prefix means that blank lines are allowed in the environment.

[image]

A few other comments:

1. `inputenc` is no longer necessary, if the input files are UTF-8
2. first load packages, then do declarations. Stating `\title` before `\usepackage{pgfplots}` makes it hard to find things during document maintenance
3. declare your commands and environments in the preamble, not after `\begin{document}`

Comment: What means {+b} in the definition of New....?

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Added information

Comment: +1 I tested changing  your \texit{meow} in \textit{meow now\\test \i\\}. Wonderfull!

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

To understand the error it helps to indent the input to better show the structure

You get the same error from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Testing}
\author{This is a Name}
\date{June 2022}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newenvironment{fora}
  {\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {0,1,...,5}  {} {}}
  \begin
{fora}

\textit{meow}
\end{fora}

\end{document}
```

which can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{fora}
  {}
  \begin

\end{fora}

\end{document}
```

So the begin code of the evironment was  loop with a empty body (but this is never called so I demonstrate an empty begin code here)

the end code of the environment is `\begin`

so `\end`  starts by inserting `\begin` and you get an internal loop of unwanted expansions.