# Efficient way to write backslash to a file

Tags: external-files

Say I have a writer and an environment (actually an Environ) defined as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ} % www.ctan.org/pkg/environ
\newwrite\mywriter
\NewEnviron{writethis}
    {\immediate\write\mywriter{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\mywriter=writehere.txt
...
\immediate\closeout\mywriter
\input{writehere.txt}
\begin{document}
```

What I want to do is copy everything in a `writethis` environment to `writehere.txt` and include it in the document later on.

It becomes problematic when I want to write a backslash. Not just a `\textbackslash` or `$\backslash$` (in math mode) but one that can be used to write commands such as in `\textbf{abc}`. (The compiler refuses to write a `\` via `\textbackslash`.)

I know of the solution

```
\makeatletter
\begin{writethis}\@backslashchar textbf{abc}\end{writethis}
\makeatother
```

but it would be really tedious to write `\makeatletter...\makeatother` every time I need a `\`. Somewhat naively, I tried to define a command to replace the above:

```
\newcommand\back
    {\makeatletter\@backslashchar\makeatother}
```

for the sake of writing simply

```
\begin{writethis}\back textbf{abc}\end{writethis}
```

but the compiler refuses. (It says `Improper alphabetic constant. \spacefactor`, I have no clue why this `\spacefactor` pops up.)

So here is my question:

> Is there a way to write a `\` to a file, shorter than `\makeatletter\@backslashchar\makeatother`?

This may have something to do with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/how-to-make-a-real-backslash-escape-character) question (perhaps even a duplicate?). I read it but didn't understand how to use Philippe Goutet's solution.

Comment: Isn't `\immediate\write\mywriter{\detokenize\expandafter{\BODY}}` what you need?

Comment: @egreg works perfect! You can post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want an “almost verbatim” write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ} % www.ctan.org/pkg/environ

\newwrite\mywriter
\NewEnviron{writethis}
    {\immediate\write\mywriter{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}
\begin{document}

\immediate\openout\mywriter=\jobname-later.tex
\begin{writethis}\textbf{abc}\end{writethis}
\immediate\closeout\mywriter

Something

\input{\jobname-later}
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of `\jobname-later` (I use `\jobname` not to clobber my files, use whatever name you prefer):

```
\textbf {abc}
```

The space will be ignored in input.

If you want to add fixed text before and after the contents of the environment, do

```
\NewEnviron{writethis}{%
  \immediate\write\mywriter{%
    \unexpanded{<before>}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
    \unexpanded{<after>}%
  }%
}
```

where `<before>` and `<after>` stand for arbitrary TeX code. You *don't* want `\expandafter` for them, in general, which is needed in the middle term in order to get the expansion of `\BODY`.

Comment: I was playing around a bit, and strangely things like `\immediate\write\mywriter{\unexpanded\expandafter{\textbf{abc}\BODY}}` do not work. But it's just a remark, I don't need it for my purposes. (It can be solved by placing the `\textbf{abc}` in a seperate `\unexpanded\expandafter`.)

Comment: @barto Of course it doesn't work: you're just expanding `\textbf` and not `\BODY`, which is then written literally in the output file. You don't need `\expandafter` for writing `\textbf{abc}` before the body; I'd rather say you *don't* want it.

Answer (score 13):

You've already given egreg the tick for the easy part-) so I'll answer

> I have no clue why this `\spacefactor` pops up.)

You have

```
\newcommand\back
    {\makeatletter\@backslashchar\makeatother}
```

`\makeatletter` changes the catcode of `@` to make it a letter but catcodes affect the conversion of input *characters* to *tokens*. they have no effect on tokens that have already been read.

The argument to `\newcommand` has already been read tokenized and stored using the catcodes in force at this point so the definition is (showing one token per line)

```
\makeatletter
\@
b%
a%
a%
c%
k%
s%
l%
a%
s%
h%
c%
h%
a%
r%
\makeatother
```

so when `\back` is used `\makeatletter` executes but it has no effect on following *tokens* so the next token to execute is `\@` which is designed to be used next to  a `.` to affect the sentence space, its definition is

```
\def\@{\spacefactor\@m}
```

so you end up trying to assign 10000 to `\spacefactor` in vertical mode. the solution (in general, although in this case the problem can be avoided in different ways) is to change the catcodes while making the definition not while using it so:

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand\back
        {\@backslashchar}
\makeatother
```

Comment: wouldn't `\protect\xxx` or `\string\xxx` work?  or would it only survive just one expansion when more are needed?  (no time to experiment.)

Comment: Waw, I didn't expect that to work. I'd think the compiler refuses when being asked to write (or being referenced to) `\@backslashchar` in a non-atletter 'environment', but apparently we can just do this. I'll keep egreg's answer as the accepted because it is the easiest way, but thanks for shedding light on this approach!

Comment: @barto it's just the same as (say) `\section` that expands to a definition based on `\@startsection` it doesn't stop working when `@` is not a letter, so long as it's a letter when `\section` is defined. You should give the tick to me, egreg is always so _happy_ when I steal a tick from him.