# Escaping backslash within \@@input or \write18

Tags: shell-escape

### Problem

I want to include a word count in my document, using texcount. But I also want to include a comma as a thousand separator. This is the code I came up with:

```
\makeatletter\@@input|"echo `texcount -1 -sum=1,1,1,1,1,1,1 -merge -incbib -utf8 \jobname.tex`| sed `s/^\(.\{1\}\)/\1,/`| cut -c1-5"\makeatother
```

However, there are special characters in the sed command: backslash and braces. LaTeX is thus unable to run this line of code.

### Attempted Solutions

I tried escaping the backslashes and braces with `\textbackslash`, `\{`, and `\}`, but it doesn't work. I also tried substituting `\makeatletter\@@input` by `\immediate\write18`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: See also: [Efficient way to write backslash to a file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191734/efficient-way-to-write-backslash-to-a-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\@backslashchar` to access `\` as a normal punctuation character.

Comment: Do you know why I need to escape the backslashes but not the braces? Just curious.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia as long as they are balanced braces are not a problem, same as in  `\typeout{aa {bbb} ccc}`  which will show `aaa {bbb} ccc`  you only need quote `{`  if you need an unmatched one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a more advanced method:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\countwords}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\abreu_countwords:n {\c_sys_jobname_str.tex}}
   {\abreu_countwords:n {#1}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \abreu_countwords:n
 {
  \sys_get_shell:xnN
   {
    texcount ~ -q ~ -1 ~ -sum=1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ~ -merge ~ -incbib ~ -utf8 ~ #1 ~ 2>/dev/null
   }{}
   \l_tmpa_tl
  \num[group-four-digits,group-separator={,}]{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sys_get_shell:nnN { x }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\countwords

abc def ghi klm nop abc def ghi klm nop [...long nonsense omitted...]

\end{document}
```

You can also do `\countwords[somefile.tex]` in order to get the count for another file.

[image]