# escaping the backslash inside \immediate\write18 with del command

Tags: shell-escape

I pasted the following line into the DOS PROMPT/DOS Command Line:

```
del D:\myTempFolder\myTempFile.txt
```

It worked well -- I was able to delete the file `myTempFile.txt'' inside the folder`myTempFolder''. I did not use the forward slash since it has a different meaning (switches) when associated with the del command.

I was wondering if I can implement the preceding routine inside a LaTeX file, so i tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\newcommand*{\myFolderName}{myTempFolder}
\newcommand*{\myFileName}{myTempFile.txt}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{del D:\textbackslash\myFolderName\textbackslash\myFileName}%
\end{document}
```

The file ``myTempFile.txt'' was not deleted. May I know where my mistake is? I think the problem here is escaping the backslash inside \immediate\write18 with the del command.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: by the way, i compiled using pdflatex with shell-escape. it has worked with my other \immediate\write18 lines, but not with the del command.

Comment: I answered but I noticed this is a duplicate of my answer that is listed in the "Related" list at the right: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525430/1090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

`\@backslashchar`  as in

```
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{del D:\@backslashchar myFolderName\@backslashchar myFileName}%
\makeatother
```

or more simply avoid expanding the undefined tokens `\myFolderName` by using `\string`.

```
\immediate\write18{del D:\string\myFolderName\string\myFileName}%
```

Comment: trying it now sir david...

Comment: Not really: the OP wants expansion of the two commands.

Comment: hi, the solution using \@backslashchar works. however, the solution using \string did not work for me. i dont know where my error is, if i missed a package or something. just the same, thank you sirs

Comment: @egreg oh I suppose so, I thought it was a meta example and the folder was literally `myFolderName` (in the example)

Comment: @beethovengg14 in both forms here I assumed the folder and file are literally `myFolderName` and `myFileName` if  you meant them to be macros that expanded to the name they need slight adjustment

Comment: hi sir david, did you mean

\immediate\write18{del D:\string\myTempFolder\string\myTempFile}

instead of

\immediate\write18{del D:\string\myFolderName\string\myFileName}%
?

Comment: @beethovengg14 if the file is `d:\beethoven\thesis.tex`  you could use `{del d:\string\beethoven\string\thesis.tex}`  but if you mean you have `\def\MyFolder{beethoven}\def\myFile{thesis.tex}` then you need `{del d:\expandafter\string\myFolder\expandafter\string\myFile}`

Comment: i understand sir. i will try it too. thank you sir for being very helpful. in all my questions here in stackexchange, it was not without trying -- i would exhaust all i know about latex, read again and again the package word for word and in between the lines, read the latex manuals, exhaust trials-and-errors, but at some point i would really stumble, and i know its already time to seek help. thank you again. beethovengg14 of the philippines

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34395/28411), in this case it will need to add this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dosystem{%
  \@ifstar{\@tempswafalse\do@system}{\@tempswatrue\do@system}%
}
\edef\@hashmark{\string#}\edef\@lbrace{\string{}\edef\@rbrace{\string}}
\newcommand\do@system[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\\\@backslashchar
  \let\%\@percentchar
  \let\#\@hashmark
  \let\{\@lbrace
  \let\}\@rbrace
  \if@tempswa\expandafter\immediate\fi
  \write18{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

and then something like

```
\dosystem{del D:\\myFolderName\\myFileName}
```