# How to get default formatting for \chapter, \section, etc.?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'd like to use `titlesec` to make some modifications to section and chapter headings, but `titleformat` redefines the formatting entirely instead of just making modifications (e.g. if I just want to change the colour).

How do I get `titlesec` to modify instead of entirely redefine? Is this possible?

If not, how do I figure out what is the *current* formatting of `\chapter`, `\section`, etc. so that I can replicate it and make my modifications?

---

In response the request for a sample document, I guess the most basic is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

However, I'm interested in a way to find out (e.g. to print out) the current formatting of `\section` instead of simply "knowing" it for a particular configuration.

Comment: Can you give a short complete document showing your setup (like document class and style files)? What you consider as the default depends on such things.

Comment: You could switch to KOMAscript (in your case `\documentclass{scrartcl}`) and then use the `\addtokomafont{}{}` command to change single attributes of the fonts of e.g. headings.

Comment: Check the documentation of `titlesec`, section _9.2. Standard Classes_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For simple modifications such as the title colour, you can use  the light version of `\titleformat`, but have to check in `article.cls` (or `report`, or `book`) what the values of the parameters are (fontsize, weight, shape).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{IndianRed}\normalfont\bfseries\Large}

\begin{document}

\section{A short title}
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 28):

The standard classes are defined as follows (copied from `titlesec` [reference](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf#subsection.8.2), section 8.2)

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}     {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}     {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}   {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}   {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `scrartcl` does not know `\chapter`. Using the KOMA-Script command `\RedeclareSectionCommand` it is also possible to modify attributes like `beforeskip`, `afterskip`, `indent`. The default settings for these attributes can be found in the KOMA-Script documentation.

Comment: Please test your answers before posting.