# New Section Above Part Crashes When Adding Bookmarks: Missing Action

Tags: titlesec, bookmarks

I'm having an issue creating a `\book` section above `\part`.  All goes well — ToC is beautiful — until I add the `bookmark` package and then it crashes with a "Missing Action" on the first use of `\book`.

Thanks go so far to [@Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) for their answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection) for help adding the [`\subsubsubsection`][1] and to [@lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) for their comment on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/defining-custom-sectioning-commands) that led me to the `chngcntr` package.

Since I'm making `\book` above `\part`, I've read in the `titlesec` documentation that I'm supposed to do the `loadonly` package option on `titlesec` and redefine all the levels from scratch.  But I really like the rest of the sections the way they are!

I just found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339305/how-to-get-default-formatting-for-chapter-section-etc) with the default formatting and spacing of sections for standard classes (thanks to [@Miotto](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/143029/miotto)!) but I'm not sure if I still need the `\@startsection` bits of the `\subsubsubsection` bits for changing `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` ToC levels.  Do the `\toclevel@` bits do that by themselves?

Can someone either help me fix this MWE or help me decipher the `\@startsection` issue just mentioned?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

% this part breaks the whole thing at the first occurence of \book
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
            bookmarksopenlevel=6,
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            anchorcolor=blue
            }{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{chngcntr} % to change within of counters

% new book sectioning level
\titleclass{\book}[-2]{page}
\newcounter{book}
\renewcommand{\thebook}{\Roman{book}}
\titleformat{\book}{\centering\normalfont\huge\bfseries{}Volume \thebook\\\Huge}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\book}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

% attach part counter to book
\titleclass{\part}{page}[\book]
\counterwithin*{part}{book}
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalfont\huge\bfseries{}Part \thepart\\\Huge}{}{0pt}{}

% fix chapter -- somehow above broke it?
\counterwithout{chapter}{part}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

% to create a subsubsub section and have it work in between subsubsection
% and paragraph as a TOC placeholder:
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

% attach paragraph counter to subsubsubsection
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsubsubsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
% set toc levels
\def\toclevel@book{-2}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@subparagraph{6}
% set toc line styles
\def\l@book{\@dottedtocline{-2}{0em}{1.5em}}
\def\l@part{\@dottedtocline{-1}{3em}{1.5em}}
\def\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{0}{6em}{1.5em}}
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{9em}{2em}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{12em}{3em}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{15em}{3.5em}}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{18em}{4.5em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{21em}{5.5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{24em}{6.5em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\book{Explore}

\part{Intro}

\chapter{Welcome}
blah
\section{Stuff}
blah
\subsection{Dude}
blah
\subsubsection{Dudette}
blah
\subsubsubsection{Sweet}
blah
\paragraph{Hello}
blah
\subsubsubsection{Nice}
blah
\paragraph{Bye}
blah

\section{Things}
blah
\chapter{Goodbye}
blah
\section{Indeed}
blah

\book{Wander}

\part{Intro Again}

\chapter{Welcome Again}
blah
\section{Hmm}
blah

\end{document}
```

Also, I've tried the `memoir` class, but it messes up too many spacing settings to be worth my time.  I like the rest of my document as is and just want to continue the writing in a new volume while still using the `book` class.

Thank you for your time!

[1]: I did have to use `chngcntr` to relink the `\paragraph` to the new `\subsubsubsection`, but all else was great!  Really helpful stuff!

Comment: well at first you should load bookmark/hyperref later. But the main problem is that your new sectioning command `\book` defines also a command `\bookmark` and that clashes with the \bookmark command from the bookmark package. The chngctr package is no longer needed in a current latex (but doesn't harm either).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't know it made a `\...mark` as well.  That explains a lot.  I'll try calling it volume and see if that does any better!

Comment: I tried to edit that comment but missed the 5 minute mark by a few seconds.  Just wanted to say:  It did!  That's wonderful!  Thank you so much!  I'd love to accept this as the answer.  Why does `titlesec` make the `\...mark` macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Allmost) all Sectioning commands have an accompanying command to set the marks for the header. There is e.g. `\chaptermark`, `\sectionmark`, `\subsectionmark`. When `titlesec` sets up a new sectioning command it therefor defines also a `\...mark`  command. And so your `\book` creates a `\bookmark` which clashes with the command `\bookmark` command from the bookmark package.

Using another name e.g. `\volume` resolves the problem.

`bookmark` loads `hyperref` and so should normally be loaded after all other packages (with a few exceptions) but before you define the new counter.