# A problem with counters

Tags: counters, expansion

While trying to answer a question I came upon a problem with counters and I need some help. The idea is to collect answers to some numbered exercises, so the collected answers can be all typeset at some later point in the document; my approach was to use the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package to, well, collect the answers:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{answers}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{answer}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{answers}%
    {\par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Answer to~\theexercise}}%
    {\par}%
    {}%
    {}%
  }
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{ex}
  {\refstepcounter{exercise}\par\noindent This is exercise~\theexercise}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
\end{ex}
\begin{answer}
This is the answer to exercise 1 but it is numbered 3.
\end{answer}

\begin{ex}
\end{ex}
\begin{answer}
This is the answer to exercise 2 but it is numbered 3.
\end{answer}

\begin{ex}
\end{ex}
\begin{answer}
This is the answer to exercise 3 and it is numbered 3.
\end{answer}

\includecollection{answers}

\end{document}
```

However, as it was expected, using this approach, all the answers receive the number corresponding to the last value of the `exercise` counter and not the number associated to their corresponding exercise (see the image). How can this be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to expand `\theexercise` before doing the write:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{answers}

\newcommand\mycollect[1]{%
  \collect{answers}
    {\par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Answer to~#1}}
    {\par}
    {}{}%
}

\newenvironment{answer}
  {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\mycollect{\theexercise}}\x}
  {\endcollect}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{ex}
  {\refstepcounter{exercise}\par\noindent This is exercise~\theexercise}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
\end{ex}
\begin{answer}
This is the answer to exercise 1 but it is numbered 3.
\end{answer}

\begin{ex}
\end{ex}
\begin{answer}
This is the answer to exercise 2 but it is numbered 3.
\end{answer}

\begin{ex}
\end{ex}
\begin{answer}
This is the answer to exercise 3 and it is numbered 3.
\end{answer}

\includecollection{answers}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I knew it was an expansion problem, but couldn't solve it. I need to study expansion more.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've simplified the code