# Save counter value inside command?

Tags: macros, counters, expansion

I'm trying to automatically generate commands based on the value of a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{count}

\newcommand\generator[1]%
{%
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\thecount}%
}

\generator{one}
\generator{two}

\begin{document}
  \one
  \two
\end{document}
```

the expected output would be "12" instead of "22".

Comment: @adam Thanks! I'm constantly visiting this wonderful site, for any doubt (at least) one answer can be found!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an expansion problem; `\thecount` needs to be expanded first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{count}

\newcommand\generator[1]%
{%
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\thecount}%
}

\generator{one}
\generator{two}

\begin{document}
  \one
  \two
\end{document}
```

[image]

This was similar to a problem I had and motivated [A problem with counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161187/3954); I inititially used basically **egreg**'s approach from [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161188/3954) there, but **egreg** himself has pointed out [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164069/save-counter-value-inside-command#comment376471_164071) that in this case it's enough to use `\edef`; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm really a newbie with latex, have supposed the expansion problem but no idea about how to solve it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup` trick is not necessary here; just `\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\thecount}` is sufficient.

Comment: one can do `\expandafter\def\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\the\csname c@count\endcsname}` but it is arguably quite some trouble to avoid an `\edef`.

Comment: In fact, it works! why?

Comment: @manuel `\edef` makes the required expansion.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've got it!

Answer (score 5):

if you need only the value and not its representation use :

```
\newcommand\generator[1]{%
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{\arabic{count}}}
```

Comment: @hebert This also works too! what is the different between \thecount and \arabic{count}?

Comment: write after the counter definition `\renewcommand\thecount{\alph{count}}` and see what happens with these two answers.