# How can I access and store the current value of a counter?

Tags: macros, counters

My counter is being updated by a command and I want to save the current value + 1 of this counter at a specific point so that later on I am able to print it out.

```
\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{tempcounter}

\def\storevalue#1{
  \setcounter{tempcounter}{\value{counterA}}
  \refstepcounter{tempcounter}

  \def\tempA{\arabic{tempcounter}}
  \let\tempB\tempA

  \expandafter\def\csname data:\string#1\endcsname{\textbf{Value \tempB}}%
}

\def\getvalue#1{\csname data:\string#1\endcsname}
```

And in the body of my document I would have something like

```
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue\vala
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue\valb
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue\valc

\getvalue\vala

\getvalue\valc

\getvalue\valb
```

And I would like this to be the output in the pdf

```
Value 2

Value 5

Value 4
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets compilable! That means start with `\documentclass` and end the tex code with `\end{documentation}` ...

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164069/172926

Answer (score 3):

No need for 'weird' 'expansion', the tools of storage are already there if `\label` is used and `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package if expandable retrieving is required, otherwise fall back to `\ref` instead of `\getrefnumber`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{tempcounter}

\newcommand{\storevalue}[1]{%
  \setcounter{tempcounter}{\value{counterA}}%
  \refstepcounter{tempcounter}\label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\getvalue}[1]{\getrefnumber{#1}}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{counterA}% Should be 1 now
\storevalue{vala}% Store 2
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{valb}% Store 4 
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{valc} % Store 5

\getvalue{vala} % 2

\getvalue{valc} % 5

\getvalue{valb} % 4

\end{document}
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez: The counter is set temporarily set, as you can see, then `\refstepped`, i.e. if initially `7`, the new value is `8`, which is stored to the label as well. The output of my solution is exactly what the O.P. wants.

Comment: In some situation a problem might be that `\storevalue` does change `\@currentlabel` to the value of the scratch-counter `tempcounter` permanently.  Perhaps calling `\refstepcounter` and `\label` should take place within a local scope/group.(When loading the **hyperref** package also, you will get anchors for hyperlinking to the place in the document that corresponds to the place where `tempcounter` was refstepped whenever `\storevalue` is used. `\@currentHref` will be changed globally as that is done by the package in terms of a `\global`-assignment...)

Comment: @UlrichDiez: Such cases may come in if `hyperref` is used -- but there is no information on that, as such I don't change my answer.

Comment: The permanent change to `\@currentlabel` due to refstepping a scratch-counter (`tempcounter`) also happens without hyperref.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? I expanded the stored value rather than just assigning a macro to it that changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{counterA}

\def\storevalue#1{

  \edef\tempA{\the\numexpr\value{counterA}+1}

  \expandafter\edef\csname data:\string#1\endcsname{\noexpand\textbf{Value \tempA}}%
}

\def\getvalue#1{\csname data:\string#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue\vala
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue\valb
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue\valc

\getvalue\vala

\getvalue\valc

\getvalue\valb
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be a little more elegant to put `\textbf` in `\getvalue` (without that `\noexpand`).

Comment: @zetaeffe Well, then it would be a bit pointless IMHO, the answer is not so much about printing some boldface texts but about `\edef` vs. `\def` and there it is important to know the `\noexpand` thingy for more delicate applications.

Comment: Ok, you're right.

Comment: @marmot Why do you use two `\edef` ? The things that go into the `\edef` for `\tempA` could go into the `\edef` for `\csname data:\string#1\endcsname` directly.

Comment: @UlrichDiez This answer is not on how to spare one `e`. There is nothing wrong with the `\edef` where I am using it, in fact, I feel it is more transparent that way.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to issue two `\par` commands at each usage of `\storevalue`.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of endlines and blank lines in definitions.

You're doing unnecessary assignments and miss the crucial expansion when you define `\data:<name>`.

I avoided pseudo-control sequences, preferring plain names, but it's up to you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{tempcounter}

\newcommand\storevalue[1]{%
  \setcounter{tempcounter}{\value{counterA}}%
  \stepcounter{tempcounter}%
  % the following must be \edef or \protected@edef if you have
  % more material that would fail in \edef such as \textbf
  \expandafter\edef\csname data:#1\endcsname{%
    \noexpand\textbf{Value \arabic{tempcounter}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\getvalue[1]{\csname data:#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{vala}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{valb}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{valc}

\getvalue{vala}

\getvalue{valc}

\getvalue{valb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For saving counter-values and retrieving them throughout the entire document, the LaTeX 2ε-kernel provides the `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism. Heiko Oberdiek's package [**refcount**](https://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) provides means for retrieving things expandably if this is needed.

**But all these things are restricted to saving and retrieving values of counters that were stepped by the `\refstepcounter`-command.**

Saving and retrieving an arbitrary `⟨number⟩` can be implemented by means of Heiko Oberdiek's package [**zref**](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref).

What a `⟨number⟩` is is elaborated in the **TeXbook**, *Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode* and in [**The ε-TeX manual**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf), section *5.1 Mode-Independent Commands*.

A `⟨number⟩` does not necessarily need to come from a LaTeX counter.

A `⟨number⟩` can, e.g., also be the result of evaluating an expression of type number, i.e., a `\numexpr`-construct. `\numexpr` can be used for calculations. Expressions like `\numexpr` are explained in [**The ε-TeX manual**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf), section *3.5 expressions*.

---

---

The example below provides the following macros:

```
\StoreNumber{⟨label⟩}%
            {⟨number⟩}
```

`\StoreNumber` evaluates `⟨number⟩` and creates a zref-referencing-label whose name is `⟨label⟩` for retrieving the result of that evaluation.

---

```
\StorePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{⟨label⟩}%
                               {⟨prefix phrase⟩}%
                               {⟨number⟩}%
                               {⟨postfix phrase⟩}
```

`\StorePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix` evaluates `⟨number⟩` and creates a zref-referencing-label whose name is `⟨label⟩` for retrieving the result of that evaluation. By means of the same zref-referencing-label you can also retrieve `⟨prefix phrase⟩` and `⟨postfix phrase⟩`. The two phrases get stored in "detokenized fashion". I.e., they will not be expanded/evaluated at the time of creating the zref-referencing-label.

---

```
\RetrieveNumber{⟨label⟩}
```

`\RetrieveNumber` retrieves the `⟨number⟩` associated to the zref-referencing-label `⟨label⟩`.

---

```
\RetrievePrefix{⟨label⟩}
```

`\RetrievePrefix` retrieves the `⟨prefix phrase⟩` associated to the zref-referencing-label `⟨label⟩`.

---

```
\RetrievePostfix{⟨label⟩}
```

`\RetrievePostfix` retrieves the `⟨postfix phrase⟩` associated to the zref-referencing-label `⟨label⟩`.

---

```
\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{⟨label⟩}
```

`\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix` retrieves

- the `⟨prefix phrase⟩` associated to the zref-referencing-label `⟨label⟩`
- the `⟨number⟩` associated to the zref-referencing-label `⟨label⟩`
- the `⟨postfix phrase⟩` associated to the zref-referencing-label `⟨label⟩`.

---

In terms of these macros, you can, e.g., define macros

```
\storevalue{⟨label⟩}
```

and

```
\getvalue{⟨label⟩}
```

for saving and retrieving specifically the result of incrementing the value of `counterA` by 1:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\storevalue[1]{%
  \StoreNumber{#1}{\the\numexpr\value{counterA}+1\relax}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\getvalue[1]{\textbf{Value \RetrieveNumber{#1}}}%
```

---

As with everything related to the `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism it takes at
least two LaTeX-runs until everything turns out correctly.

---

---

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

%--<stuff only needed for making the example looking good>-----------------
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amstext}
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfpagewidth\endcsname\relax\else
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname pagewidth\endcsname\relax\else
  \pagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pageheight=\paperheight
\fi
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth by -2cm
\oddsidemargin=1cm
\advance\oddsidemargin by -1in
\advance\oddsidemargin by -\hoffset
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight\paperheight
\advance\textheight by -2cm
\topmargin=1cm
\advance\topmargin by -1in
\advance\topmargin by -\voffset
\pagestyle{empty}%
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\medskipamount
\newenvironment{makeverbatimnice}{\topsep=0ex\partopsep=0ex\ignorespaces}{}%
\newcommand\ThingsName[1]{\textsf{``#1''}}%
\newcommand\meta[1]{\textit{\textlangle#1\textrangle}}%
%--<eof stuff only needed for making the example looking good>-------------
%
%--<stuff needed for implementing the user-macros>-------------------------
\usepackage{zref}
\makeatletter
% My variant of \@bsphack / \@esphack.
\newskip\MYNAMESPACE@savsk
\newcommand*\MYNAMESPACE@bsphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode\MYNAMESPACE@savsk\lastskip\@savsk\lastskip\@savsf\spacefactor\fi
}%
\newcommand*\MYNAMESPACE@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@\nobreak\hskip\z@skip\fi
      % The following \hskips are used for restoring \lastskip.
      % I hope there are no evil side-effects. ;-)
      \nobreak\hskip-\MYNAMESPACE@savsk
      \nobreak\hskip\MYNAMESPACE@savsk
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi
}%
%
\newcommand\MYNAMESPACE@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\MYNAMESPACE@RefUndefText{%
      \texorpdfstring{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}{??}%
    }%
  }{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\MYNAMESPACE@RefUndefText{%
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%
\zref@newprop{numbertostore}[0]{0}
\zref@newprop{numberprefix}[]{}
\zref@newprop{numberpostfix}[]{}
%
\DeclareRobustCommand\StorePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix[4]{%
  \MYNAMESPACE@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \zref@setcurrent{numberprefix}{\detokenize{#2}}%
  \zref@setcurrent{numberpostfix}{\detokenize{#4}}%
  \expandafter\MYNAMESPACE@Exchange\expandafter{%
    \expandafter{\the\numexpr\number#3\relax}%
  }{%
    \zref@setcurrent{numbertostore}%
  }%
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{numbertostore,numberprefix,numberpostfix}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \MYNAMESPACE@esphack
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\StoreNumber[2]{%
  \MYNAMESPACE@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\MYNAMESPACE@Exchange\expandafter{%
    \expandafter{\the\numexpr\number#2\relax}%
  }{%
    \zref@setcurrent{numbertostore}%
  }%
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{numbertostore}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \MYNAMESPACE@esphack
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\RetrieveNumber[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numbertostore}{\MYNAMESPACE@RefUndefText}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\RetrievePrefix[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numberprefix}{\MYNAMESPACE@RefUndefText}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\RetrievePostfix[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numberpostfix}{\MYNAMESPACE@RefUndefText}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numberprefix}{}%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numbertostore}{\MYNAMESPACE@RefUndefText}%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{numberpostfix}{}%
}%
\makeatother
%--<eof stuff needed for implementing the user-macros>---------------------

\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}

\begin{document}

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

The \meta{number} stored as \ThingsName{First Stored Number} is retrieved
via \verb|\RetrieveNumber{First Stored Number}|:
\RetrieveNumber{First Stored Number}%

The prefix associated with the \meta{number} stored as
\ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved via
\verb|\RetrievePrefix{Second Stored Number}|:
\RetrievePrefix{Second Stored Number}%

The \meta{number} stored as \ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved
via \verb|\RetrieveNumber{Second Stored Number}|:
\RetrieveNumber{Second Stored Number}%

The postfix associated with the \meta{number} stored as
\ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved via
\verb|\RetrievePostfix{Second Stored Number}|:
\RetrievePostfix{Second Stored Number}%

Everything associated with the \meta{number} stored as
\ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved via
\verb|\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{Second Stored Number}|:\\
\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{Second Stored Number}

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

\ThingsName{counterA} is set to 7.
\setcounter{counterA}{7}%

\ThingsName{counterB} is set to 14.
\setcounter{counterB}{14}%

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

A \meta{number} is stored as \ThingsName{First Stored Number} via
\begin{makeverbatimnice}
\begin{verbatim}
\StoreNumber{First Stored Number}%
            {\the\numexpr\value{counterA}*\value{counterB}/2\relax}%
\end{verbatim}%
\end{makeverbatimnice}%
\StoreNumber{First Stored Number}%
            {\the\numexpr\value{counterA}*\value{counterB}/2\relax}%

\emph{(The expression evaluates to 49 as
\(\text{\texttt{\string\value\string{counterA\string}}}%
\cdot
\text{\texttt{\string\value\string{counterB\string}}}\,/\,2%
=7\cdot14\,/\,2=49\).)}

A prefix phrase, a \meta{number} and a postfix phrase are stored
under \ThingsName{Second Stored Number} via
\begin{makeverbatimnice}
\begin{verbatim}
\StorePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{Second Stored Number}%
                               {The number }%
                               {\the\numexpr\value{counterB}+3\relax}%
                               { is a prime number.}%
\end{verbatim}%
\end{makeverbatimnice}%
\StorePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{Second Stored Number}%
                               {The number }%
                               {\the\numexpr\value{counterB}+3\relax}%
                               { is a prime number.}%

\emph{(The expression evaluates to 17 as
\(\text{\texttt{\string\value\string{counterB\string}}}+3=14+3=17\).)}

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

The \meta{number} stored as \ThingsName{First Stored Number} is retrieved
via \verb|\RetrieveNumber{First Stored Number}|:
\RetrieveNumber{First Stored Number}%

The prefix associated with the \meta{number} stored as
\ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved via
\verb|\RetrievePrefix{Second Stored Number}|:
\RetrievePrefix{Second Stored Number}%

The \meta{number} stored as \ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved
via \verb|\RetrieveNumber{Second Stored Number}|:
\RetrieveNumber{Second Stored Number}%

The postfix associated with the \meta{number} stored as
\ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved via
\verb|\RetrievePostfix{Second Stored Number}|:
\RetrievePostfix{Second Stored Number}%

Everything associated with the \meta{number} stored as
\ThingsName{Second Stored Number} is retrieved via
\verb|\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{Second Stored Number}|:\\
\RetrievePrefixAndNumberAndPostfix{Second Stored Number}

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

\newpage

In terms of these macros you can, e.g., define macros \verb|\storevalue|
and \verb|\getvalue| for saving and retrieving specifically the result 
of incrementing the value of \ThingsName{counterA} by 1:
\begin{makeverbatimnice}
\begin{verbatim}
\DeclareRobustCommand\storevalue[1]{%
  \StoreNumber{#1}{\the\numexpr\value{counterA}+1\relax}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\getvalue[1]{\textbf{Value \RetrieveNumber{#1}}}%
\end{verbatim}%
\end{makeverbatimnice}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\storevalue[1]{%
  \StoreNumber{#1}{\the\numexpr\value{counterA}+1\relax}%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\getvalue[1]{\textbf{Value \RetrieveNumber{#1}}}%

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

\verb|\getvalue{vala}|: \getvalue{vala}%

\verb|\getvalue{valc}|: \getvalue{valc}%

\verb|\getvalue{valb}|: \getvalue{valb}%

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

\begin{makeverbatimnice}
\begin{verbatim}
\setcounter{counterA}{0}%
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\storevalue{vala}%
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\storevalue{valb}%
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\storevalue{valc}%
\end{verbatim}%
\end{makeverbatimnice}%
\setcounter{counterA}{0}%
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\storevalue{vala}%
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\storevalue{valb}%
\stepcounter{counterA}% You can also use \refstepcounter but you don't have to.
\storevalue{valc}%

\hbox to\textwidth{\null\hrulefill\null}%

\verb|\getvalue{vala}|: \getvalue{vala}%

\verb|\getvalue{valc}|: \getvalue{valc}%

\verb|\getvalue{valb}|: \getvalue{valb}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having fun I offer a variant which makes use of ε-TeX's expressions of type number and where expansion/evaluation of such an expression is not triggered via `\edef` but via cascades of `\romannumeral`-expansion and exchanging arguments. (The picture below is borrowed from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474949/118714) as the results with our answers look the same.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{counterA}

\newcommand\MYNAMESPACEexchange[2]{#2#1}%

% In case you trust in \storevalue's argument not containing mean
% things like \GobbleToEndcsnameAndInsertEndcsname with
%
%   \long\def\GobbleToEndcsnameAndInsertEndcsname#1\endcsname{\endcsname}
%
% , which would, e.g., remove an \expandafter in front of 
% \endcsname, you can do:
%
%\newcommand\storevalue[1]{%
%  \expandafter\def\csname data:#1\expandafter\endcsname
%  \expandafter{%
%    \expandafter\textbf\expandafter{%
%      \romannumeral0%
%      \MYNAMESPACEexchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
%      \expandafter\MYNAMESPACEexchange
%      \expandafter{\the\numexpr\arabic{counterA}+1\relax}{Value }%
%    }%
%  }%
%}%
%
% If you don't trust in that, then do:
%
\newcommand\storevalue[1]{%
  \expandafter\MYNAMESPACEexchange\expandafter{\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \MYNAMESPACEexchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\MYNAMESPACEexchange\expandafter{\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral0%
      \MYNAMESPACEexchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
      \expandafter\MYNAMESPACEexchange
      \expandafter{\the\numexpr\arabic{counterA}+1\relax}{Value }%
    }}{\textbf}%
  }}{\expandafter\def\csname data:#1\endcsname}%
}%
\newcommand\getvalue[1]{\csname data:#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{vala}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{valb}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\storevalue{valc}

%\expandafter\show\csname data:vala\endcsname
\getvalue{vala}

%\expandafter\show\csname data:valc\endcsname
\getvalue{valc}

%\expandafter\show\csname data:valb\endcsname
\getvalue{valb}

\end{document}
```

[image]