# How to reduce one counter

Tags: macros, counters, etoolbox, collect, expandafter

In the MWE below, the `excoutP` is added to store the value of `excout`.
How can we only use the counter `excout`?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{collect}
    \definecollection{excol}
    \newcounter{excoutP}
    \def\st{}
    \newcommand{\inso}{
        \refstepcounter{excoutP}
        \appto\st{\theexcoutP}
        \st
    }
    \newcounter{excout}
    \newenvironment{exam}{
        \refstepcounter{excout}
        \begin{center}
            THE EXAM \textcolor{red}{\theexcout}
        \end{center}
        \begin{collect}{excol}{}{}{}{}
            The exam {\Large \textcolor{red}{\inso}} 
        \end{collect}
    }{}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{exam}
    Content 1
    \end{exam} 
    \begin{exam}
    Content 1
    \end{exam} 
    
    \bigskip
    \includecollection{excol}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Mr @egreg has had a related answer.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161187/a-problem-with-counters/161188#161188

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting counter in `exam` environment. We can expand the counter to `collectTempt` command, collect the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{excol}

\newcounter{excout}

\newcommand{\collectTempt}[1]{
    \begin{collect}{excol}{}{}{}{}
        The exam {\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}} 
    \end{collect}
}

\newenvironment{exam}{
    \refstepcounter{excout}
    \begin{center}
        THE EXAM \textcolor{red}{\theexcout}
    \end{center}
    \begingroup\edef\xttt{\endgroup\noexpand\collectTempt{\theexcout}}\xttt
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{exam}
Content 1
\end{exam} 
\begin{exam}
Content 1
\end{exam} 

\bigskip
\includecollection{excol}
\end{document}
```