# Changing style of "Proof of..."

Tags: theorems

In reference to the answer in [How to place all proofs automatically in appendix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/how-to-place-all-proofs-automatically-in-appendix)

I would like to change the style of "Proof of..." (proofs put in the end) to bold faces for instance, but I don't want to change the style of the other proofs along the text. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etex,etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\crefname{ineq}{inequality}{inequalities}
\creflabelformat{ineq}{#2{\upshape(#1)}#3}
\usepackage{enumitem} % do away with indentation on my lists
\crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{cor}{Corollary}{Corollaries}
\crefname{ass}{Assumption}{Assumptions}
\crefname{df}{Definiton}{Definitons}


\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@fourthoffour}[4]{#4}
% We define an addition for the theorem-like environments; when
% \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} is declared, the macro \thm expands
% to {...}{...}{...}{Theorem} and with \@fourthoffour we access
% to it; then we make available \@currentlabel (the theorem number)
% also outside the environment.  
\def\fixstatement#1{%
  \AtEndEnvironment{#1}{%
    \xdef\pat@label{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \@fourthoffour\csname#1\endcsname\space\@currentlabel}}}

% We allocate a block of 1000 token registers; in this way \prooftoks
% is 1000 and we can access the following registers of the block by
% \prooftoks+n (0<n<1000); we'll use a dedicated counter for it
% that is stepped at every proof
\globtoksblk\prooftoks{1000}
\newcounter{proofcount}

% We gather the contents of the proof as argument to \proofatend
% and then we store
% "\begin{proof}[Proof of <theoremname> <theoremnumber>]#1\end{proof}"
% in the next token register of the allocated block
\long\def\proofatend#1\endproofatend{%
\edef\next{\noexpand\begin{proof}[Proof of \pat@label]}%
\toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\value{proofcount}\relax=\expandafter{\next#1\end{proof}}
\stepcounter{proofcount}}

% \printproofs simply loops over the used token registers of the
% block, freeing their contents
\def\printproofs{%
\count@=\z@
\loop
\the\toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\count@\relax
\ifnum\count@<\value{proofcount}%
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}
\makeatother

% Here starts the example, with two theorem declarations    
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\fixstatement{thm}
\fixstatement{lem}


\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{cor}[definition]{Corollary}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \cref{addition}]
(state your proof here)
\end{proof}

\begin{lem}\label{addition}
$1+1=2$
\end{lem}
\proofatend
It's quite clear.
\endproofatend

\begin{thm}
$1+2=3$
\end{thm}
\proofatend
Obvious from lemma \cref{addition}.
\endproofatend

\begin{cor}
$1+2=3$
\end{cor}

\appendix
\section[Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]
{Proof of \cref{addition}}
\begin{proof}
Assume...
\end{proof}

\section*{Proofs}

\printproofs


\end{document}
```

PS.: There are too many packages being loaded because I want to make sure there are no conflicts with packages I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\long\def\proofatend#1\endproofatend{%
  \edef\next{\noexpand\begin{proof}[\noexpand\normalfont\noexpand\bfseries Proof of \pat@label]}%
  \toks\numexpr\prooftoks+\value{proofcount}\relax=\expandafter{\next#1\end{proof}}
  \stepcounter{proofcount}}
```

Answer (score 2):

since you're using `amsthm`, you can redefine the `proof` environment to supply a
"generic" font command for the heading font, and then replace that when you go to print
the proofs:

```
\newcommand{\proofheadfont}{\itshape}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
%       \itshape
        \proofheadfont
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}

\def\printproofs{%
\renewcommand{\proofheadfont}{\bfseries}
...
```

(i'm sure this can be done with a patch, but i haven't been able to make that work.)