# send text right before end of document

Tags: macros

I'm writing documents which only contain exercises and I would like to add some hints for some exercises.

What I want is that the hints are specified in the exercise itself but displayed at the end of document.

I've tried to use the `\atEndDocument` hook but it did not worked.

Here a short example of what I want to write

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}    
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=7mm] 

\begin{document}
Exercise 1 : 
Solve the following equation $x^2+1=2$
\hint{Exercise 1 : Don't forget that two solutions exist}

Exercise 2 :
Derivate the following function $f:x \to \cos(x^2)$
\hint{Exercise 2 : The result is not $-\sin(x^2)$ }
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: if you want help with an error make your example demonstrate the error, and say exactly what error message you got.

Comment: You could adapt the code in the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/how-to-place-all-proofs-automatically-in-appendix

Comment: It appears that the pgf packages prevent from the use of the "\atBeginDocument"

Comment: @M.Miguel-Brebion No, they do not (perhaps you just mistyped it (the command starts with A not a )  If you had shown the error message that you got some could have debugged it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun:  This solution saves the hints as macros for later expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{nhint}
\newcommand{\hint}[1]% #1 = paragraph
{\stepcounter{nhint}\expandafter\gdef\csname hint\thenhint\endcsname{#1}}% global, just in case

\begin{document}
Exercise 1 : 
Solve the following equation $x^2+1=2$
\hint{Exercise 1 : Don't forget that two solutions exists}%

Exercise 2 :
Derivate the following function $f:x \to \cos(x^2)$
\hint{Exercise 2 : The result is not simply $-\sin(x^2)$ }%

{\section{Hints}}% turn off \@afterheading

\edef\total{\arabic{nhint}}% or \countdef\total 0 \total=\value{nhint}%
\setcounter{nhint}{0}%
\loop\ifnum \value{nhint}<\total
  \stepcounter{nhint}%
  \csname hint\thenhint\endcsname
  \par
\repeat

\end{document}
```

---

This solution stores the hints in a savebox.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\hints}
\setbox\hints=\vbox{}

\newcommand{\hint}[1]% #1 = paragraph
{\global\setbox\hints=\vbox{\unvbox\hints
  \parindent=0pt% set up formatting here
  \strut#1\strut\par}%
}

\begin{document}
Exercise 1 : 
Solve the following equation $x^2+1=2$
\hint{Exercise 1 : Don't forget that two solutions exists}

Exercise 2 :
Derivate the following function $f:x \to \cos(x^2)$
\hint{Exercise 2 : The result is not simply $-\sin(x^2)$ }

\section{Hints}

\unvbox\hints

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple working example with the `\AtEndDocument` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtEndDocument{\vfill}
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\AtEndDocument{\par #1}}
\begin{document}
Exercise 1 : 
Solve the following equation $x^2+1=2$
\hint{Exercise 1 : Don't forget that two solutions exists}

Exercise 2 :
Derivate the following function $f:x \to \cos(x^2)$
\hint{Exercise 2 : The result is not simply $-\sin(x^2)$ }

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution does not work when some packages (such as pgfpages) also calls \atEndDocument{\clearpage}