# Appendixify: Move selected slides to appendix in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, appendices, navigation, write

When working with Beamer I often have slides that I initially write in the body of the presentation, then decide they should be consigned to an appendix. This is also useful when reapplying slides from a long talk to a briefer occasion. Effectively, though, this results in an appendix whose sections parallel the body of the talk.

Cutting and pasting a slide from the body TeX loses the cohesion of the sections there. It would be nicer to be able to mark some slides as appendix slides, and let a macro rebuild the section structure in the appendix to parallel.

Thus:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{appendixify}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello world}
\begin{frame}{1}\end{frame}
\appendixify{\begin{frame}{2}\end{frame}}
\begin{frame}{3}\end{frame}

\section{Farewell world}
\appendixify{\begin{frame}{4}\end{frame}}
\begin{frame}{5}\end{frame}

\appendix
\appendixified
\end{document}
```

should render as if it were:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello world}
\begin{frame}{1}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{3}\end{frame}

\section{Farewell world}
\begin{frame}{5}\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{Hello world}
\begin{frame}{2}\end{frame}

\section{Farewell world}
\begin{frame}{4}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, this macro might also generate navigation widgets to flip from a section to the corresponding appendix section, and back again; or flag that there is one or more appendix slide following a particular body slide by providing a link to them, thus allowing the presenter to optionally detour via the appendix deck. (Obviously there will be some side-effects like macro references will reflect the state at the time of appendix, not the place of insertion.)

I have attempted to implement a macro to write marked content to an auxiliary file -- or to keep them in memory -- then reproduce them in the appendix (not worrying about reproducing the document structure). But - alas! - I am defeated, and would love to see someone else contribute this feature, or give me the building blocks to do so myself. (The chief building block I am missing is writing content verbatim to a file.)

Comment: I might actually find what I need here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20957/how-to-use-a-write-command-inside-a-newenvironment

Comment: I think you still have problem with sections, i have an idea of partial solution that could help, i'll post it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beamersubframe` package provides a convenient way to move frames to the backup without moving the actual code around:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[append]{beamersubframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{subframe}
    moved to appendix
\end{subframe}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\appendix

\appendsubframes
\end{document}
```

For section navigation etc. the one from the parent section will be shown on the "appendixified" frames.

*For detailed information on creating convenient navigation to and from the appended frames, please see the package documentation.*

Comment: +1 This package also replicates the section structure as wished in the question.

Comment: @dexteritas Oh really! That is even better than I thought. Do you know what needs to be changed to replicate the section structure?

Comment: There's nothing to do. I just added a beamer theme, that shows the current section in the header to test it.

Comment: @dexteritas Ah, yes. It uses the section navigation etc. from the parent section. I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. Probably not good, but it works for me.

```
% Moving slides to appendix
% Define a variable to store everything to move
\newcommand{\backupSlides}{}
% Define command to append text to backup variable
\newcommand{\backup}[1]{
\expandafter\def\expandafter\backupSlides\expandafter{\backupSlides#1}
}
```

To appendixify a frame simply put it into a backup command:

```
\backup{
    \begin{frame}...\end{frame}
}
```

At the end of your document add (once for all frames):

```
\backupSlides
```

Comment: It's a useful start, but does not attempt to replicate the section structure as sought.

Comment: `\backupSlides` does not produce anything...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first attempt that seems to provide section cloning and moving to the appendix (although I changed the macro names to be a little more self-documenting). But I'm very unfamiliar with TeX macro hacking, and I'd like some suggestions to make it more idiomatic, safe, and functionality-complete.

**Update**: this seems to create all sorts of rendering errors for me, not least that any `\hline`s have disappeared from my appendix `tabular`s, so really I would love to see a real TeX/Beamer hacker rewrite it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\appendix@out
\immediate\openout\appendix@out\jobname.adx

\newcommand\toappendix{\obeylines\expandafter\toappendixArg\noexpand}

\newcommand\toappendixArg{
    \begingroup
        \@bsphack%
        \let\do\@makeother\dospecials%
        \catcode`\^^M\active%
        \def\verbatim@processline{%
            \immediate\write\appendix@out{\the\verbatim@line}}%
        \verbatim@start}

\def\endtoappendix{\endgroup}
\let\oldAppendix\appendix
\def\appendix{\immediate\closeout\appendix@out\@esphack\oldAppendix}
\def\makeappendix{\input{\jobname.adx}}
\let\oldSection\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
    \immediate\write\appendix@out{\unexpanded{\oldSection{#1}}}\oldSection{#1}}
\let\oldSubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection[1]{%
    \immediate\write\appendix@out{\unexpanded{\oldSubsection{#1}}}\oldSubsection{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Hello world}
\begin{frame}{1}\end{frame}

\begin{toappendix}
    \begin{frame}{2}\end{frame}
\end{toappendix}
\begin{frame}{3}\end{frame}

\section{Farewell world}
\begin{toappendix}
    \begin{frame}{4}\end{frame}
\end{toappendix}
\begin{frame}{5}\end{frame}

\appendix
\makeappendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to remember *all* counters then. I was thinking if frame-2 could be compiled as usual and be `\includepdf`ed later.

Comment: Could you give me a sense of when it will be a practical issue that I've not remembered all counters?

Comment: Won't includepdf make other issues with slide counters? We still want this to act like an appendix... Also, there seem to be other problems with this approach: my `\hline`s are not showing up, for one thing.

Comment: Your approach is **canonical** and it should always work. By counters I mean equation-numbering or figures or so. The problem with `\includepdf` is that one cannot simply include (part of) itself.

Comment: Well, even if it *should always work* it doesn't seem to work. It's making a mess of sections in the body and the appendix...

Comment: this is just a good idea, the only limitations (well not really) is it does not check if section contien an appandix frame so all sections will apper towice

Comment: I actually think whether *all* sections are replicated is a matter of taste/application, @touhami. Replicating all sections, even where some are empty, will make appendix a visual reflection of the main slides. I agree that there should be an option to our hypothetical package for "only non-empty".

Yet I'm getting all sorts of rendering errors with the current implementation that are greater issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newwrite\mtwrite
\immediate\openout\mtwrite=app\jobname

\newif\ifsec
\newif\ifsubsec

% this is not the best way to redefine (sub)section \command
\let\mtsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
\mtsection{#1}%
\def\mtsec{#1}%
\sectrue\subsecfalse}

\let\mtsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
\mtsubsection{#1}%
\def\mtsubsec{#1}%
\subsectrue}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appendixify}[1]{%
\ifsec
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string\section{\mtsec}}
\secfalse\fi%
\ifsubsec
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\string\subsection{\mtsubsec}}
\subsecfalse\fi%
\immediate\write\mtwrite{\unexpanded{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Hello world}
\subsection{and hellow}

\begin{frame}{1}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{2}\end{frame}

\section{Farewell world}

\appendixify{\begin{frame}{3}\end{frame}}
\begin{frame}{4}\end{frame}

\subsection{and world}

\appendixify{\begin{frame}{5}\end{frame}}
\begin{frame}{6}\end{frame}

\section{Last  word}
\subsection{and last}

\appendixify{\begin{frame}{7}\end{frame}}

\subsection{and last end}

\begin{frame}{8}\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{9}\end{frame}

\immediate\closeout\mtwrite
\let\section\mtsection
\let\subsection\mtsubsection
\input{app\jobname}
\end{document}
```

it would be better if one save the contents into a toks or a macro rather than write to external file.

Comment: Great! It works for cases mine breaks on. However, it seems to be incompatible with frame macros like `\newcommand{\stopcenter}{\end{center}}
\newenvironment{centerframe}[1]{%
\begin{frame}[environment=centerframe]
\frametitle{#1}
\begin{center}
}{\stopcenter
\end{frame}
}`. Any idea why these can't be appendixified, e.g. `\appendixify{\begin{centerframe}{title}Contents\end{centerframe}}`

Comment: the problem is that `centerframe` doesn't work even in normal mode (without `appendixify`). You can redefine it like this `\newenvironment{centerframe}[1]{% 
\begin{frame}[environment=centerframe] \frametitle{#1}\center}{\endcenter\end{frame}}`